# How can I record my screen?

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast, desktop-recording

How can I record my screen on Ubuntu?

The app I'm looking for has ideally all of these features:

1. Can record in a format that can be played back easily on any platform and/or accepted by YouTube or another popular video site
2. Can record just a window (instead of the whole screen), possibly selecting it with a mouse click
3. Can start recording after a configurable delay (e.g., I launch the app and have time to do arrangements to my desktop/window before actual recording starts)

Comment: Take a look to [this ranking](https://www.slant.co/topics/1405/~screen-recorders-for-linux).

Comment: I wish I had 10 rep so I could answer this question... The answer is so simple. Sometimes we don't see the forest through the trees. This is not an Ubuntu problem therefore all the Ubuntu solutions are not needed. Simply use any video conference software such as Zoom or Google Hangouts, share your screen, record the call, and voila you are done. These programs already capture your voice and audio output so there is literally nothing it can't do... This solution will work on any operating system except maybe mobile devices. LOL! Too bad I won't get any points for this genius answer :unamused:

Comment: Doesn't answer this specific question, but for those looking for a very basic screen recorder, see the built-in recorder: [screencast docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html#screencast)

Answer (score 305, accepted):

## [gtk-recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) [image: install gtk-recordmydesktop]

> Adds an easy to use graphical icon on the GNOME toolbar to make a pleasure use and configure the audio and video capture and screencast application recordMyDesktop.

[image]

As mentioned at [20.04: Can't install gtk-recordmydesktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236345/20-04-cant-install-gtk-recordmydesktop) and on the [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtk-recordmydesktop&searchon=names), the package is not available on the main repository anymore, and `sudo apt install gtk-recordmydesktop` fails. I'm not sure why the http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk-recordmydesktop link seems to work, maybe it installs an older version. But this indicates that the software is not being actively supported.

## recordmydesktop

This is the non-GUI backend of `recordmydesktop`, and it is [still available in 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=recordmydesktop&searchon=names):

```
sudo apt install recordmydesktop
recordmydesktop --on-the-fly-encoding
```

This will record until you stop the program on the terminal e.g. with Ctrl + C.

`--on-the-fly-encoding` encodes the output immediately; without it you need to wait for a possibly long time at the end for the encoding to be done. I haven't seen any significant downsides to that option yet, likely it will just take a bit more of CPU resources, but it is generally worth it.

It should be able to do everything that gtk-recordmydesktop does, but it is a bit harder to learn as you have to deal with the command lines.

You can set a stop recording shortcut e.g. with:

```
recordmydesktop --stop-shortcut=Control+s
```

You can select to record a single window as shown at: [How can I get the value of Window ID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153451/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-window-id/423568#423568)

```
recordmydesktop --windowid `xwininfo | grep 'id: 0x' | grep -Eo '0x[a-z0-9]+'`
```

This will allow you to first select the window with a mouse click, and it starts recording after you click.

How to record sound output with it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/how-can-i-record-the-sound-output-with-gtk-recordmydesktop

## [xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/) (no longer maintained, package is no longer available)

> A screen capture enabling you to capture videos off your X-Window desktop for illustration or documentation purposes. It is intended to be a standards-based alternative to tools like Lotus ScreenCam.
>
> Video can be saved in MPEG or AVI files format.

Comment: Thanks for these two suggestions!  I've tried them both, but could get neither to do what I need: `gtk-recordmydesktop` insists on recording the whole virtual screen (3200x1200), which is way too large... `xvidcap` lets me select a rectangular area of the screen to be recorded, but then wants to place its control buttons on top of it (and moves the area if you move the controls), which doesn't work for recording a window almost as tall as the screen (I'm using a tiling window manager).

Comment: Success with the command-line version of `xvidcap`: xvidcap --audio no --file testvid.avi --cap_geometry `xwininfo | fgrep geometry | cut -c12-`.  This won't work with windows that don't report pixel-based geometry (e.g., `xterm`), so one should give the recording window location explicitly as widthxheight+x+y, as in `xvidcap ... --cap_geometry 1336x1170+0+0`

Comment: We've removed xvidcap from the repository now because it's no longer maintained.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri: `gtk-recordmydesktop` does allow you to record only a selected screen area. Just drag a rectangle in the preview area.

Comment: Actually select what window to record by using the windowid option. You can check the window id of a window using the xwininfo utility

Comment: gtk-recordmydesktop gets Linux-screenrecording crappiness to a new level. It actually recorded different parts at different FPS :D Audio syncing (which of course fails) is REALLY hard after this.

Comment: Beware: this is buggy if you are using Gnome3. Pressing record makes the control window disappear, thus you can't stop recording without kill -9.

Comment: gtk-recordmydesktop, its video quality is very bad and it get long time for render

Comment: I cannot get your first suggestion work in Ubuntu 16.04. It does not store the file in /tmp. Please, add a possible example here.

Comment: The output video produced by `gtk-recordmydesktop` is pretty distorted.

Comment: Note, that recordmydesktop have a timing [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/recordmydesktop/+bug/570133) when using "Encode On the Fly" option. And it is not likely to be fixed since development stopped in 2009.

Comment: I should mention that if using the commandline version, to avoid a really low framerate you should increase the bitrate from the default of 450000 to 2000000. Like this: `recordmydesktop --v_bitrate 2000000 -o output.ogv`. Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=3749812#post3749812

Comment: `recordmydesktop` is a very tiny program (between 80 kB and 180 kB) and `gtk-recordmydesktop` is just its front-end written in Python (ironically, much larger than `recordmydesktop` itself; around 0.5 MB). It creates OGV videos  The resulting video seems OK to me when I increase FPS in the advanced settings.

Comment: Tried to install on Debian 9 and encountered: `File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package gtk-recordmydesktop (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gtk-recordmydesktop
...` Looks like Python 3 is not supported :S

Comment: the audio is quite distorted

Comment: As of 2019-08-12 on 18.04 LTS: audio track is out of sync (lags behind).

Comment: it seams `gtk-recordmydesktop` have some issues on ubuntu 20.04, the UI window just disappears as soon a I start recording.

Comment: 'gtk-recordmydesktop' gives black screen to the recording on 2.0.04

Comment: The first grep of `xwininfo | grep 'id: 0x' | grep -Eo '0x[a-z0-9]+'` works for me, but not the second - I get nothing back. (So I just took it by hand from xwininfo.)

Comment: For me, the `--on-the-fly-encoding` flag makes the audio track out of sync. running `recordmydesktop` without this flag fixed it. @DmitrySomov

Answer (score 196):

## Kazam

It's a good application for this purpose:
[Home](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/), [install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kazam), or simply `sudo apt install kazam`

It gives you a delay before recording. Recording is done in HD and the output is in .mkv format which is accepted for YouTube so there is no need to convert and re-render.

There are some [useful keyboard shortcuts](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2015/08/kazam-keyboard-shortcuts.html) too:

> To start the recording: <kbd>Super + Ctrl + R</kbd> 
> To pause the recording: <kbd>Super + Ctrl + P</kbd>
> To stop the recording: <kbd>Super + Ctrl + F</kbd>
> To show/hide main window: <kbd>Super + Ctrl + W</kbd>

On Ubuntu 20.04 I met this bug with it where the video is not captured/or is all black: https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/issues/9 even though recordmydesktop video capture worked on the same machine.

Comment: I installed kazam but the output for mp4 is .movie and when I try to play it it gives me "there is no application for sgi video files" Also I cant locate the stop button on gnome.

Comment: I had glitch issues with recordMyDesktop, while Kazam works just fine. It is also faster as it generates an mp4 right away as soon as you finish recording.

Comment: I tried it, it has problems with webm format which is smaller than mp4, good thing is that records speakers and mic and saves file right away. I will try vokoscreen now.

Comment: This should be the standard. Outputs mp4, video doesn't tear up, and gives pause before recording.

Comment: wow, I capture 90 second screen by kazam and exported video size was 3.2Gb

Comment: That's odd, I just did during the last 2 months 29 videos that range from 5 minutes to 30 minutes. The 30 minutes were 400MB (1080p resolution and showed desktop and web sites). The 5 minutes to 10 minutes were around 70MB to 100MB). I have been using Kazam since 2014 I find it better and easier than any of the ones mentioned here so far.

Comment: UI is much better than recordmyesktop.

Comment: -1 for kazam. Adds an offset to the mouse so it is seen as 100px to the right of its actual position. Dissapointing

Comment: If anyone likes to know kazam keyboard shortcuts: https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2015/08/kazam-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: I was getting fuzzy footprints of windows I was opening and closing in recordmydesktop app, but after downloading kazam it worked nice with clean and crisp audio/video recording.

Comment: best one there is. yet unfortunately, no way to actually change the compression rate besides fps.

Comment: Installing via 'sudo apt-get install kazam' gave me an error regarding docker! `Setting up docker-ce (18.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Very strange. I managed to install it from   the Ubuntu Software app. (16.04)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation, the recorder worked like a charm. Amazing design, quality and simplicity.. it might be the best desktop app for recording I've ever used.

Comment: I just recorded a 10-second video and it gave me avi video of size 1.5GB!!

Comment: This only records a black screen.

Answer (score 191):

I like Byzanz; it records your activity as a GIF file.

[image]

It's pretty light and works well, especially for putting a shorter screencast on a webpage or in an email.

You can either get it from the PPA (might have a more up-to-date package but is 'unsupported'):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/byzanz
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install byzanz
```

Or you can get it from the official Ubuntu repositories by clicking the button below:

[image: Install Byzanz]

For further information:

[How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

Comment: To record GIF screencasts, I am using Silentcast (https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/), which is far more ergonomic IMO.

Comment: This app is not yet for Ubuntu 16.04. It would be great to get it.

Comment: @Masi actually it is in the [official repositories](http://askubuntu.com/a/123515/453746) for command line, but I haven't seen this GUI before.

Comment: how to launch this one?

Comment: I got some 404s when installing :(

Comment: Anybody have an easy way to figure out offset coordinates for this other than trial and error?  I like the simplicity of `byzanz` *except* that I'd really like to be able to drag-select a region, similar to `gnome-screenshot`.

Comment: It is available for 16.04, and you don't have to add a repository to get it. Just `sudo apt install byzanz` and it goes. Cons: low frame rate and doesn't capture full resolution or color space, so colors get distorted and shapes get aliased and motion is choppy.

To figure out what parameters to give it, use the `xwininfo` command, click in the window you want to record, and it will tell you the x, y, width, and height that `byzanz` wants.

Comment: As of 2019, byzanz supports webm format, so no more GIF 256-colour palette artifacts.

Answer (score 146):

### Simple Screen Recorder

**[SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)**  is a Linux program that I've created to record programs and games. There are programs that can do this, " but I wasn't 100% happy with any of them, so I created my own "

My original goal was to create a program that was just really simple to use, but as I was writing it I started adding more and more features, and the result is actually a fairly complex program. It's 'simple' in the sense that it's easier to use than ffmpeg/avconv or VLC :).

**For Ubuntu versions 12.04 - 16.10 it is not in the standard repositories and can be installed with the following:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
# if you want to record 32-bit OpenGL applications on a 64-bit system:
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

**For Ubuntu versions 17.04 - onwards it is included in the `universe` repository and can be  installed by:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

Here is a UI preview:

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious after installation how you use your simplescrrenrecorder. what command gives hat interface?

Comment: @DrewV well you can start by searching in dash > simple screen , from command line you can open terminal and type simplescreen tab tab and enter

Comment: Is hard to just record and save(as kazam does, but kazam has its problem too with webm), it's hard to record both mic and speakers. I will try vokoscreen.

Comment: @Drewverlee `$ simplescreenrecorder ` gives the interface

Comment: I've just installed this and after a bit of working through the settings I've been able to record just a window of the screen which is all I needed and it works simply really well. Thank you.

Comment: Must say, this is a very usefull app, easy install, works as expected, well done. I uninstalled gtk-recordmydesktop for this. select rectangle ftw!

Comment: The only complex thing about this is the long name :-)

Comment: It's amazing! Very simple and intuitive, and has great functionality and quality.

Comment: Everything is black

Comment: simplescreenrecorder is the best!

Comment: update in 2021, This still works. And works well. Good work :)

Comment: @Qasim video is not being recorded, is this because I'm using Wayland instead of X11? Also headset audio and microphone sound cannot be recorded at the same time using simplescreenrecorder.

Comment: How is this - an app in **official** repository, easy to use, choosable screen part to record, simply working as expected - so down below ? O.o

Comment: I just tested simplescreenrecorder because I wanted to record two windows side by side, and the select rectangle feature, along with how it did just work first time right after install, makes this a great pick. Nice work.

Comment: Best, works like a charm!

Comment: Does not work with Wayland.

Answer (score 77):

Recently I tried to record a screencast with audio. I tried many of the options listed here and other websites. My goal was not to write a comprehensive summary of all tools available, but to find a single one which works.

In my case (after several hours of struggling) it was **VOKOSCREEN** which worked, so I did not look further.
My system is Linux Mint 15 Olivia, 64-bit, which is based on Ubuntu Raring.

This is my summary/log which I wrote while experimenting. Hope it will save you several hours:

- **avconv**: audio and video get out of sync, audio is lagging behind. Tried all the options I could. This is the command line I used:

  ```
  avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -vcodec wmv1 -acodec pcm_s16le -q 7 b4.avi
  ```
- **Byzanz**: creates animated gif (not tried, since I need sound as well and longer screencast)
- **Eidete**: unable to install (with 20 years of Linux experience, didn't try forever though)
- **gtk-recordmydesktop**: creates ogg which is fine, but unable to convert to anything. Best converter was mencoder but is speeds up video (but not audio) so they get out of sync.
- **istanbul**: freezes immediately
- **Kazam**: if record area larger than ~640x480 memory starts leaking, leaving at most a few minutes before system becomes unresponsive. Many have reported similar issue, this is a known bug.
- **pyvnc2swf**: Is a tool to record a VNC session. Not convenient if you want to record your own screen (not tried)
- **screenkey**: advertised as a "screencast tool", but is not about recording your screen
- **tibesti**: seems to be no longer maintained (since 2011), does not even install
- **vokoscreen**: FINALLY!!!!
  Quality is good: both audio and video.
  After recording, I could compress the file to about 1:7 with mencoder without any loss of quality.
  I discovered that it uses the following command line:

  ```
  ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -sameq -r 15 my.avi
  ```
- **xvidcap**: As stated above: "We've removed xvidcap from the repository now because it's no longer maintained." (not tried)
- **wink**: distributed as downloadable executable not as package, (not tried)

Comment: Am pretty sure the bug mentioned for Kazam is gone because I have recordings from 2015 and 2016 that go beyond 30 minutes (Biggest is 2 hours 19 minutes) with no problems at all and perfect recorded session.

Comment: The bug was fixed in 2.0.13

Comment: Getting an error `Cannot open display :0.0,0,` while using ffmpeg command

Comment: +1 for the ffmpeg code. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For me it recorded only a few seconds. Using Ubuntu 22 LTS. After switching away from wayland (setting on login screen) it worked nice. As described in other places that tell that wayland in Ubuntu 22 makes many screencast software unusable.

Answer (score 48):

This is what I use to make screencasts, the cli command that comes with `recordmydesktop`

```
recordmydesktop --width 1920 --height 1200 --full-shots --fps 15 --channels 1 --device hw:1,0 --delay 10
```

The delay 10 gives me 10 seconds to "prepare" my desktop before it starts recording. When I'm done I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then it starts encoding the file.

I have a dual display, and the width/height argument lets me focus recording on one of my monitors. By adjusting this value I can also record onto my second monitor.

Other pointers:

- Install [screenkey [image: Install screenkey]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=screenkey) for a slick overview for screencasts.
- Ubuntu [Screencast Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreencastTeam/RecordingScreencasts)

Comment: Look up [`recordmydesktop --help`](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/manpage.php) via terminal for more info (or just click the link).

Comment: How did you get the coordinates?

Comment: RecordMyDesktop 3.8 creates invalid files which are hard to recode, edit, and YouTube doesn't accept them. I advice to avoid it.

Answer (score 32):

You can also use ffmpeg to create a screencast. Example:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -r 25 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 /tmp/output.mpg
```

Notes:

- 0.0 is your display.screen number of your X11 Server. You can get the
  number with `echo $DISPLAY`
- -r = frames per second
- -s = resolution

---

To get audio:

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/audio -f x11grab -s 1280x1024 -r 3 -ab 11 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mp4
```

Comment: and how does one get audio as well?

Comment: Ah, I found the way: ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/audio -f x11grab -s 1280x1024 -r 3 -ab 11 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mp4

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04, use avconv instead of ffmpeg.

Comment: Also good examples on the wiki page: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: If you have a large screen e.g. 1920x1080 but want the video resolution to be small e.g. 720p (1280x720), make sure you put the `-s 1280x720` [after the input source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321618/356625): `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 24 -i :0.0 -s 1280x720 ~/Videos/output.mp4`

Answer (score 31):

## [**Vokoscreen**](http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html)

A new screencasting tool for Linux

[image: vokoscreen screenshot]

### Installation

Since Ubuntu 20.04 there's a package:

```sh
sudo apt install vokoscreen-ng
```

Previously you needed a PPA:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vokoscreen-dev/vokoscreen # For latest version
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vokoscreen
```

Alternatively, using snap:

```
snap install vokoscreen-ng
```

- Source [on Github](http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html)
- [Here for more help](http://www.unixmen.com/vokoscreen-a-new-screencasting-tool-for-linux/).

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 13.04 / Raring x86.

Comment: this does not seem to have an option to choose one of the monitors -- if you have a multiple monitor setup

Comment: Vokoscreen is indeed a fantastic small tool. Link to the [Github](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen).

Comment: No need of PPA? `apt-cache policy vokoscreen`. @Aras v2.4.0 seems to have that option.

Comment: I use vokoscreen on Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed one small problem though: the video recordings are moving "fast". I mean,  if you create a video of yourself and other people and animals, when viewing the video, you will notice that you all move almost as fast as in the old classical black-and-white movies from the beginnings of cinematography. I have tested this several times, using all kinds of settings - same weird result!

Comment: Also *vokoscreen-ng* is available in *universe* repository since Ubuntu focal (20.04LTS)

Answer (score 31):

## GNOME built-in desktop recorder

Gnome 3 already seems to have a very simple thing to do record Screencasts - you can assign what shortcut it uses in Keyboard settings. It records the entire screen, and records directly into a webm file (a fairly widely used format) into `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR` - by default `"$HOME/Videos"`.

1. By default, to start recording, press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R</kbd>. You'll see a circle displayed on top right corner to indicate recording is in process.
2. To Stop recording, press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R</kbd> again.

**Source**: [Screenshots and screencasts on Gnome Help page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en)

[[image: example screencast] 

<sup>The above image should be animated - if you have animations disabled it won't work. Click to view the file</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhtwu.gif)

If you want to convert the image to a animation, [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/556031/277135) is very helpful - the best method is to basically:

> Another command-line method would be to export the movie to frames
> using ffmpeg:
>
> ```
> mkdir frames
> ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=320:-1 -r 10 frames/ffout%03d.png
> ```
>
> Then use convert from ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) to make your
> animated GIF:
>
> ```
> convert -delay 5 -loop 0 frames/ffout*.png output.gif
> ```

This is how I did the above animation, with the exception that I added `-dither None -colors 80 -fuzz "40%" -layers OptimizeFrame` to the convert command*, and cropped the result in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

<sup>*Be careful with these options, some like using *ALL* of the CPU</sup>

Comment: Have [this annoying bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665548).

Comment: how can i record one screen?

Comment: I find it useful to increase the maximum recording time from the default of 30 seconds: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length 600`.

Comment: also see [how to change screencast duration in gnome3 screen recorder](https://askubuntu.com/q/919807)

Comment: does not capture my audio either from microphone or audio from applications like a browser

Answer (score 20):

### [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/)

[image: screenshot]

But this works really well. The main reason why I use it is because I can record both my microphone **AND** monitor output with ease.

Plus you can stream to Twitch if you'd like.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg obs-studio
```

If you don't want to add the PPA you can also [download the deb file](https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio) and installed with `sudo dpkg -i <debfile>`.

---

The benefit of `OBS` is that you can preset many recording options like screen recording and webcam. Whenever you need to start recording just select the preset recording option and start recording. Along with that while screen recording you need not to select windows/ grab screen every time. It have option to select whole screen or just a specific area of page on `google-chrome` or `Firefox` or libre-doc. In this case it just keep on recording that specific selected area of that application irrespective of what you are viewing on your screen and even if you resrat. You can see real time preview. This saves a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Underappreciated answer. This should be up top.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm finding OBS Studio is the easiest screencast software on Lubuntu 22.04. The choice of video sources is the only confusing thing: either window or screen worked for me. You can explicitly choose the window and record when needed, mix microphone and monitor sound live and so on. Kazam and Vokoscreen make it harder to control which window you are recording.

Answer (score 14):

[**Tibesti**](https://launchpad.net/tibesti)

> Tibesti Screencaster is a program for Ubuntu that allows you to record your screen and your microphone and/or audio out sounds.

[image: Screenshot from OMG!Ubuntu!]

To install add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ackondro/+archive/tibesti) `ppa:ackondro/tibesti` ([How to add a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) and then install tibesti from the software center.

Alternatively, open a terminal and paste:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ackondro/tibesti
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tibesti
```

Comment: First thing i looked was the last changelog. I like it that it says 2011. And it looks like it is progressing nicely for when natty comes out. i will try it out but i read it does not yet work with 3D OpenGL stuff.

Comment: @alukik, can i got this code sudo apt-get install tibesti, that's would be work?

Comment: user13499, the answer has been updated with step-by-step instructions from console.

Comment: @alaukik I've found the framerate to be terrible and there doesn't seem to be a framerate setting, and "record audio out" doesn't seem to work, which is a great pity - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the framerate issue has resolved itself

Comment: Afaik, tibesti does not install on ubuntu 11.10. A pity, because it looks really interesting to me.

Comment: This seems to be available upto natty(11.04) only.

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/).

- [Download](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/download.htm) (freeware; Windows and Linux).
- [Wink UserGuide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/11399044/Wink-User-Guide).

There are two tutorial projects created in Wink which you can view. Use the `Help`, `View` tutorial menu options to render and view them before you start using Wink.

Features as told on their website:

- Freeware: Distributed as freeware for business or personal use. However if you want to redistribute Wink, you need to get permission from the author.
- Cross-Platform: Available for all flavours of Windows and various versions of Linux (x86 only).
- Audio: Record voice as you create the tutorial for explaining better.
- Input formats: Capture screenshots from your PC, or use images in BMP/JPG/PNG/TIFF/GIF formats.
- Output formats: Macromedia Flash, Standalone EXE, PDF, PostScript, HTML or any of the above image formats. Use Flash/html for the web, EXE for distributing to PC users and PDF for printable manuals.
- Multilingual support: Works in English, French, German, Italian, Danish, Spanish, Serbian, Japanese, Brazilian Portuguese and Simplified/Traditional Chinese.
- Smart Capture Tools: Capture screenshots automatically as you use your PC, based on mouse and keyboard input (great time saver and generates professional captures).
- Performance/Quality: Creates highly compressed Flash presentations (few kbs to few hundreds of kbs, much smaller than competing commercial products) ideal for using on the web.

Tutorials:

- Youtube [Basic steps](http://youtu.be/mb9u7IhdAAo), [Wink 2.0 Tutorial](http://youtu.be/Ta1VnYOyxas)
- [maketecheasier.com](http://maketecheasier.com/make-screencasts-with-wink/2008/12/01)

[image]

Comment: installer.sh from official package: "This installer only has x86 binaries. Sorry." ...

Answer (score 13):

### How to create an animated (GIF) screenshot

Added bonus with this approach is that you can post the screencast without embed tags on any forum that includes animated GIFs as embedded like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-or-move-the-icons-in-the-unity-launcher/39819#39819)

The answers prior to mine have clearly answered how to create a video screencast. Now if you just want to show an animated screenshot, essentially an extremely short screencast in an image format (GIF, and not more than ~10 sec), it's also easy.

First create a screencast of what you want to show in the animated GIF. Then follow the instructions below...

You'll need Gimp, mplayer (**WARNING!** NOT mplayer2) and mencoder. Issue the following commands to install them.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
sudo apt-get install mplayer
sudo apt-get install mencoder
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Alternatively, you can install them from the Synaptic package manager that comes with Ubuntu.

The following command breaks your screencast into a number of jpeg or png (based on which command you choose) images:

```
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 2 eagles.avi -vo jpeg:outdir=Desktop/animated
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 2 eagles.avi -vo png:z=9:outdir=Desktop/animated
```

*Where, `-ss 0:0:33` tells mplayer where you begin (0 hours, 0 minutes, 33 seconds), `-endpos 2` tells mplayer where to stop (2 minutes), `z=9` sets compression level for the output png images to 9, `Desktop/animated` is the directory (~/Desktop/animated/) where you want the images to be output to.*

You can also tell mplayer where to stop, as a specific time, like so:

```
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 0:1:12 eagles.avi -vo jpeg:outdir=Desktop/animated
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 0:1:12 eagles.avi -vo png:z=9:outdir=Desktop/animated
```

Now you have the images, but you need to combine them into a single, animated GIF. This is really simple:

- Start Gimp > File > Open as Layers > browse to the directory (~/Desktop/animated/), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all images, and click 'Open'.
- Simple hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or go to File > Save As... and name the image as 'animated**.gif**' > hit 'Save' > check 'Save as Animation' radio button > hit 'Export' > in the next window, simply hit 'Save' unless you know what you are doing.

That's it. You have your animated GIF ready!

**Here's an example:**

[image: Animated GIF screenshot]

**PS:** I am not very comfortable with the terminology when it comes to this kind of stuff, but I hope I am clear nevertheless. :)

**SOURCE:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhJtyblE_D0

Answer (score 13):

Check out [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek). You can record screencast of a selected region and save it as GIF.

[image: Recording screen using peek]

You can install the latest version of Peek on Ubuntu from its [PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~peek-developers/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install peek
```

Comment: It was already installed on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: No need to use `add-apt-repository` anymore. Peek now is available from the default repository.

Comment: Note that Peek has been marked as deprecated by its authors.

Answer (score 12):

After trying everything, this is the solution I came up with:

**Note:** The "fake" `ffmpeg` from Libav has been depreciated (within Libav) and has been replaced by `avconv` from Libav. The "deprecated" message does not apply to the real `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg which is unaffected and is still under heavy development.

First install the required codecs:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-5*
```

Use the following command to record the screencast:

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1280x800 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame myscreencast.mkv
```

Change `-s 1280x800` to whatever resolution you like.

### more examples

#### all screen with given resolution and sound

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264  -threads 0 output.mkv
```

#### all screen with mouse following and sound

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -show_region 1 -follow_mouse 100 -r 10 -s 960x540 -i :0.0+10,200 -acodec pcm_s16le -qscale 0 -threads 0 output.mkv
```

#### Detailed options I know are following

- `-f`: input file format
- `-i`: input file name
- `-r`: fps (Frame Per Second)
- `-s`: frame size (width x height)
- `-i :0.0+10,200`: size of squared area to follow

Comment: if you have two monitors, how do you select one of them to record?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) as follows:

1. Launch VLC media player and select `Media > Open Capture Device`:

   [image]
2. Set `Desktop` at `Capture mode`:

   [image]
3. Enter desired frame per rate for the capture and select `Convert` at bottom:

   [image]
4. Provide path to the file to which you want to save your screen capturing by `Browse` button and click on `Start` to start recording:

   [image]
5. Click on Stop button when you finish.

You'll get the screen recorded/captured in the file.

Comment: thank you - do you know if this is also capable of capturing keystrokes?

Answer (score 9):

This bash script is based on ffmpeg. It calculates the required resolution and record your desktop in high-definition.

```bsh
Xaxis=$(xrandr -q | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1)
Yaxis=$(xrandr -q | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f2)
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s $(($Xaxis))x$(($Yaxis)) -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq ~/Video/output.mkv
```

Change the filename to your taste. This script can be found on github [here](https://github.com/dilawar/Scripts/blob/master/record_my_desktop.sh).

Comment: `ffmpeg -s cif` is a way to avoid `xrandr` calls!

Comment: @gavenkoa `cif` is a [video size alias](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-size) for `352x288` which is a size I doubt anyone wants to use.

Comment: OK, all this sizes can be found in `man 1 ffmpeg-utils`...

Answer (score 8):

Check out this article about [Screenkey](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/screenkey-desktop-recording-tool-displays-key-presses-on-screen/)

It turns your key strokes into highly readable subtitles overlaid on the recording.  It seems like it would be incredible for tutorial and training type videos about CLI-based topics.

Not positive it fits all the original criteria, I will try to update later.

It's on Launchpad [here](https://launchpad.net/screenkey)

Comment: this makes for a great comment, not an answer.

Comment: News version of screenkey is at https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 18.04/GNOME 3 have a built-in feature of recording screen for 30 seconds. <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R</kbd> to start or stop recording.

Videos will be saved in WebM format in videos folder

You can increase it by installing  **dconf Editor** from Ubuntu Software. Follow these steps:

1. Open `dconf-editor` and type *screencast*, this will let you jump to schema `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`.
2. Edit the 30 of `max-screencast-length` key to required value (set it to **0** to make it stop when you hit <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R</kbd> to stop recording)

You can also edit the shortcut if you need to change.

Answer (score 6):

> Kdenlive is a free open-source video
>   editor for GNU/Linux and FreeBSD,
>   which supports DV, AVCHD and HDV
>   editing. Kdenlive relies on several
>   other open source projects, such as
>   FFmpeg, the MLT video framework and
>   Frei0r effects.

http://www.kdenlive.org/features

Answer (score 1):

Scshoot is open-source cross-platform (Java) screen capture and recording tool: http://github.com/edartuz/scshoot

Besides of single-image capture, can record part of screen to animated PNG (APNG) or video.

Comment: The github repo not exist

Answer (score 1):

**ScreenStudio**

ScreenStudio is a top notch screen recording software. There are no dependencies beside the need for the JRE 8.0 (OpenJDK).

Features:

- Record video from the webcam during screencast
- Record audio from both the microphone and the speakers
- Allows you to select which screen you want to record if there are multiple screens.
- Customizable FS(Frames per second)
- You can chose the desired resolution for recording video from the webcam.
- Stream directly to YouTube live, Twitch.tv, HitBox and Upstream.
- Screencast live over UDP
- Supports FLV, MOV and MP4 formats.

**Installing ScreenStudio in Ubuntu 16.04**

First make sure that you have either OpenJDK 8 or OracleJDK 8 before installing

Open a terminal and type

```
java -version
```

If it shows something like this then you have Java 8 installed.

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Otherwise you need to install it.

Steps to install OpenJDK can be found here:

[How can I install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759451/how-can-i-install-openjdk-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Steps to install OracleJDK can be found here:

http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/

Install ScreenStudio -

**Method 1:**

ScreenStudio isn’t included in Ubuntu repository. The Ubuntu PPA contains version 2.3

Steps to install:

Open terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:soylent-tv/screenstudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenstudio
```

**Method 2:**

Go to

http://screenstudio.crombz.com/archives/ubuntu/

At the time of writing this article the latest version is:  3.09

Download it. Use Nautilus file explorer to go to the download directory and extract the archive using default archive manager.

Go to ScreenStudiosrc --> apps --> Ubuntu

Using Nautilus open a terminal at the target folder. Smply right click on any empty space of the folder and select *open in terminal*

In terminal type the command:
    ./ScreenStudio.sh

and the application will launch

If you want to create a desktop shortcut for the software type in terminal:
    ./createDesktopIcon.sh

**How to use ScreenStudio features?**

ScreenStudio is so much rich in features that it can be explained only through video tutorial.

Refer the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52V6UJ4y-ME

CREDITS: Patrick Balleux

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Soapbox](https://wistia.com/soapbox), which is a great extension developed for Chrome. It records your camera, mic, and screen all together.

After you're done recording, you can use their online editor to select during what sequences of the recording you want to show your screen, your camera, or both.

Answer (score 1):

### [asciinema](https://asciinema.org)

A fast/lightweight way to record the terminal:

> Forget screen recording apps and blurry video. Enjoy a lightweight, purely text-based approach to terminal recording.

- **Install**: `sudo apt install asciinema`
- **Record**: `asciinema rec`
- **Stop**: Type `exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

Then will give you the option to upload (public or private) or just generate the file on disk.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

`CTL + ALT + SHIFT + R`
to start
`CTL + ALT + SHIFT + R`
to stop
Saved in /home/$USER/Videos as .webm files

Comment: In which system does this work and which software does it use?

Comment: linux ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: how do you play the webm file?

Answer (score 1):

OBS Studio worked for me.

It has the most advanced features I've seen - can record your entire screen or just a window, and can also be used for streaming your screen and other stuff I didn't even use.

Warning: It's only for advanced users.

Comment: I'm finding OBS Studio is by far the easiest screencast software on Lubuntu 22.04. You can explicitly choose the window and record when needed, mix microphone and monitor sound live and so on. I wouldn't say it was only for advanced users. The interface on Kazam is extremely simple, but as with Vokoscreen you can capture the wrong window or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the great suggestions here. My recommendation for tools that will work great for recording audio, video and editing the screencast is Camtasia and Screenflow. If you're looking for more ideas on recording your screen and creating an engaging screencast then check out this post: http://www.mediacore.com/blog/how-to-record-your-screen-and-create-engaging-screencasts It includes tons of tools and tips on audio, video and editing your screencast

Comment: It would be much better if you could provide a summary of what's included in the linked article. This way if the link becomes unavailable, your answer will remain helpful.

Answer (score 0):

just use kooha it runs fine with wayland

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo  #  https://flathub.org/home

flatpak install flathub io.github.seadve.Kooha
```

then launch by hitting the `Windows` key and search for `kooha`

for details see  https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.seadve.Kooha

Comment: Screen area selection not work with cinamon.