# Good screencasting programs for Ubuntu?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

What are the best video screen capturing programs for Ubuntu as far as reliability, performance, and ease of use go?

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki.

Comment: Disagree -- if I'm interested in screencasting, I won't be looking for screenshot tools.

Answer (score 0):

KAZAM !

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:and471/kazam-daily-stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kazam
```