# What is the best screen video+audio capture programm for dual monitor?

Tags: screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

There are many video tutorials on youtube. What software should I use for creating a video tutorial?

I installed xvidcap (software center 10.04) but it seems not support 2 Monitors, when I click on record xvidcap disappear does not capture the screen.

Write here down what software you use?

Comment: yes close to duplicate, but he brings up an additional problem. namely lack of dual monitor support

Comment: I can address the dual monitor issue in the duped question