# How do I get the CPU temperature?

Tags: hardware, cpu, temperature, monitoring, sensors

How do I get the CPU temperature?

Comment: Related: [hardware sensors](http://askubuntu.com/q/33976/62483), [indicator](http://askubuntu.com/q/371922/62483) and [fan control](http://askubuntu.com/q/63588/62483).

Answer (score 797, accepted):

**Install [lm-sensors](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lm-sensors) [image: Install lm-sensors]**

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

After installation type the following in terminal

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

You may also need to run

```
sudo service kmod start
```

It will ask you few questions. Answer Yes for all of them. Finally to get your CPU temperature type `sensors` in your terminal.

```
sensors
```

**Output:**

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +41.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +41.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

w83627dhg-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:       +1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)   
in1:         +1.60 V  (min =  +1.68 V, max =  +1.44 V)   ALARM
AVCC:        +3.30 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
VCC:         +3.28 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
in4:         +1.85 V  (min =  +1.66 V, max =  +1.11 V)   ALARM
in5:         +1.26 V  (min =  +1.72 V, max =  +0.43 V)   ALARM
in6:         +0.09 V  (min =  +1.75 V, max =  +0.62 V)   ALARM
3VSB:        +3.30 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
Vbat:        +3.18 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.30 V)   
fan1:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:        892 RPM  (min = 2136 RPM, div = 8)  ALARM
fan3:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan4:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan5:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:       +36.0°C  (high = +63.0°C, hyst = +55.0°C)  sensor = diode
temp2:       +39.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = diode
temp3:      +119.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:   +2.050 V
```

**To see HDD temperature Install [hddtemp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hddtemp) [image: Install hddtemp]**

```
sudo apt-get install hddtemp
```

**Output:**

```
$ sudo hddtemp /dev/sda        
/dev/sda: ST3160813AS: 34°C
```

Comment: This doesn't work on all hardware. On my system, `sensors` always shows a temperature of +40.0°C.

Comment: On my 13.04 system, it's `sudo service kmod start` instead of `sudo service module-init-tools start`

Comment: You can run `watch sensors` to see temperature values updating each second.

Comment: It gives warnings about being risky. Are you sure you should answer "yes" to everything? I don't think they have put those messages there for fun...

Comment: What are the three temperatures temp1, temp2, temp3? @karthick87 ?

Comment: I notice you have problems in your computer(many ALARMS), anyway I want to ask, what are in4 in5 in6 and if the reach the maximum what does that mean ?

Comment: In 2017. with systemd, it is now: `sudo systemctl start kmod`

Comment: The only output I get from the sensors command is the temp of the two cores.

Comment: to answer yes to all sensors-detect questions, run `yes yes | sensors-detect`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS already has this installed, although the output of the `sensors` command is much more brief.

Comment: and for the gpu?

Comment: What are recommended temperatures for components? Or rather, what temperatures should make me worried?

Comment: My system froze when I answered "yes" to one of the questions (about probing various I/O ports). Anyways, it had detected correct sensors for what I had wanted already so I just answered no to everything else and it still worked fine.

Comment: run `watch -n 0.1 sensors` to check every
 0.1 second

Answer (score 244):

**Quick command-line solution; [shows temperature in millidegrees Celsius (m°C)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt)**

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

**Applet**

If you are looking for a easier-to-access version, add a **Hardware Sensors Monitor** to Gnome-Panel:

1. `sudo apt-get install sensors-applet` - this will install the [sensors-applet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sensors-applet) [image: Install sensors-applet] package
2. Right-click the panel, select `Add to panel...`, then select this:
   [image]
3. You're done. You can configure which sensors are displayed by right-clicking the applet and selecting `Preferences->Sensors`.

   [image]

Comment: Your command-line solution may not work for all.Because the path will be different for every kernel version.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work for me.

Comment: My Ubuntu 12.04 system has no `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature`; in fact there's nothing under `/proc` named `temperature`.

Comment: Thats because '/proc' is deprecated; try '/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp'

Comment: +1 for quick command line option. Answer would benefit from adding more info about it (@mathepic comment and info about other paths possible).

Comment: for my 14.04 system, neither command line works (No such file or directory).

Comment: @mathepic: why is it depracted? and is /sys/... still (like proc) containing zero-sized on-demand files?

Comment: Since adding panels didn't work, I went to extensions.gnome.org to find something alike.

Comment: This is a GNOME 2 applet, so presumably it doesn't work on Ubuntu Unity (the default) or GNOME 3.

Comment: what units for `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`? Can you convert it to C/F? ... Looks like the first two digits are the first two digits preceding the decimal place and the next are those following the decimal place for Celsius.

Comment: @mathepic procfs is not depreciated, using it for non-process information is.

Comment: I got an answer `66000` running the command as given in the answer on fully updated 16.04.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Mine has `thermal_zone0`, `cooling_device0` ... `cooling_device8`.  I 'd guess it's probably the different hardware/firmware that makes the OS create these folders in different ways? (Just guessing.)

Comment: This work for me  , but I don't understand the output. The output is : `53500` .What is the meaning of it.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal These guys explain it a bit more. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-out-raspberry-pi-gpu-and-arm-cpu-temperature-command/ (basically your temp is 53c)

Comment: Thermal Zones 0 and 1 are often distorted on my Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.4+ and only Thermal Zone 2 (invisible to `sensors`) is consistently accurate.

Comment: This did not show up to be added in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in July 2017.  So I uninstalled it then did a sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: A more understandable output: `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | awk '{ print ($1 / 1000) "°C" }'`

Comment: I tried this on CentOS 7.9, and there are no `thermal_zone*` folders under `/sys/class/thermal`, only symlinks named `cooling_deviceX`, with X a number. There's no temp file under any of the folders. So this depends a lot on your distro and kernel, I believe.

Answer (score 153):

A good indicator for monitoring temperature, fan speeds and voltage is **psensor**. It shows output of all sensors, draws graphs.
Also selected outputs can be placed in indicator panel.

[image: psensor in action]

It can be installed from Ubuntu repositories by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

Newer versions of psensor can be installed from ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

It can also draw graphs when you tick the boxes in the graph column:

[image: Screenshot]

[Here is some information with more pictures.](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/psensor-updated-with-option-to-display.html)

[Another useful link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/monitor-hardware-temperature-in-ubuntu.html)

In some cases not all sensors are displayed. Then you can run

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

and answer "yes" to all questions. But is not quite safe in some cases, but I never had any real problems with that. A safer way is to take default answers.

Some additional sensors may appear.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04, `psensor` will sometimes use 30% cpu, driving the temperature up.

Comment: The problem still persists. App is unusable.

Comment: @raaj - is this bug reported somewhere?

Comment: @Eugene - is this bug reported somewhere?

Comment: After installing this my touch pad stops working at periodic times

Comment: By default, psensor detected only two cores on a quad-core CPU. Odd.

Answer (score 152):

### Temperature without third-party apps

At the time of writing, all the answers involve use of third-party utilities. If you want to find out the temperature without installing anything, use:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
20000
53000
50000
53000
56000
68000
49000
50000
```

To see what zones the temperatures are referring to use:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'
INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
SEN1             45.0°C
SEN2             51.0°C
SEN3             57.0°C
SEN4             59.0°C
pch_skylake      77.5°C
B0D4             50.0°C
x86_pkg_temp     51.0°C
```

The temperatures are stored in Celsius with 3 implied decimal places. `sed` is used to "prettify" output.

The last temperature is `x86_pkg_temp` reported at `54.0°C`. For the Skylake i7 6700HQ CPU, I used this temperature for Conky display below.

### Temperature with Conky

If you don't mind third-party utilities I like to use Conky--a light weight system monitor.

#### Conky commands

Within conky the system variable I used to monitor an Ivy Bridge CPU is:

```
${hwmon 2 temp 1}°C
```

To monitor a Skylake CPU I used:

```
${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C
```

#### Conky display

The conky display looks like this:

[image]

The temperature starts at 72°C with a single CPU running at 100% in turbo mode of 3200 MHz. Then turbo is switched off and temp drops 10°C to 62°C with a non-turbo speed of 2600 MHz. 10 seconds later turbo is turned back on and temperatures immediately spike back up to 72°C.

---

## Controlling Temperature

After knowing your temperature you probably want to control it better. `tlp` works wonders for keeping system under control. It works with `thermald`, Intel Powerclamp, Battery vs AC for USB power, etc. Although highly configurable I've never had to change the configuration settings for a pleasant Out-Of-The-Box experience. Prior to using it I had all kinds of problems with an IvyBridge laptop overheating all the time. I have it on my new Skylake laptop and the fans NEVER run except when doing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 upgrade.

You can get a very detailed write-up with installation instructions here: [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872)

Comment: what unit is this? apples? 1/1000th of °C? 59/29402th of °F?

Comment: your quote says 48000 but your text says this is 57 degrees Celsius? I'm confused.

Comment: @Sun I had regenerated the one-liner using a newer processor and didn't revise the explanation properly. Fixed!

Comment: Slight tweak to the sed command to get it to handle fractions of a degree: `sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'`

Comment: I'm wondering if there may sometimes be an extra step needed to get the kernel to actually *read* the board temperature sensors, as I'm currently getting 26.8 degrees for both a unit in my lab, and one out in the field, and I frankly don't believe the one in the field could be running that cool when the modem next to it is reporting a temperature of 42 degrees (similar to @Katu https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/854029?noredirect=1#comment1394626_891639 here)

Comment: @ncoghlan I've noticed the same thing when room temperature is 25C but sensor `INT3400 Thermal` always reports an impossible 20C. I simply ignore that sensor...

Comment: Thanks! And this is a bit off-topic, but how do you create a (such high-quality) GIF capturing a portion of the screen like that?

Comment: @JimRaynor The area is called screen recording and there is a Q&A about that here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen I'm using `peek` which you will find instructions for on the link.

Comment: beautiful customization, may I ask to share the conky config file?

Comment: This answer scraped from Ask Ubuntu has the full configuration: https://www.pippim.com/2018/06/19/Setting-to-High-Performance.html There is also a link at the top back to Ask Ubuntu if you prefer reading on this site or want to up-vote that answer.

Answer (score 45):

[hardinfo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hardinfo) [image: Install hardinfo] is very useful tools to get all hardware information.

Install hard info by `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`. Then you can get temperature by sensors.

[image: sensor]

Comment: Good looking tool, except every single page populates *except* Sensors (e.g. is blank)...

Comment: not working for Sensors

Comment: @frumbert I think it depends on `lm-sensors`!

Comment: I also like the ARP table.  Pretty handy to verify  what is connected to my subnet.

Comment: Benchmarks are quite outdated in this program though.

Comment: Works for me! Also shows me a graph in green color at the bottom. This tool is by far the best!

Answer (score 36):

After you install lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
```

run:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

you can run the following command to view hardware temps:

```
watch -n 1 sensors
```

Also, the fan is usually controled by BIOS.

---

Another good tool is `i7z` for Intel Core processors:

```
sudo apt install i7z
sudo i7z
```

and because `i7z` runs like `top`, there is no need to use `watch`.

Comment: i like the tip about using watch, it's one of my favorites. i also recommend adding the -d option to watch to highlight the differences.

Comment: This gave me 4 core temp reading on my i7-3770 on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS running 100% CPU (~77 degrees Celsius)

Comment: Good answer till you got to `i7z`. Maybe it's okay, but it has ruby dependencies. "The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato i7z javascript-common libjs-jquery libruby libruby3.1 libyaml-0-2 msr-tools rake ruby ruby-net-telnet ruby-rubygems ruby-sdbm ruby-webrick ruby-xmlrpc ruby3.1 rubygems-integration"  No Thanks.

Comment: @B.Shea What do you have against ruby?

Comment: I personally hate it, but my point was that just to get the cpu temp, it seems a overkill to install a prog that needs extras like this. I looked at the single ruby file i7z_rw_registers.rb. There was no reason I can see to use ruby for this file. (And add more dependencies and files to install). Shell, perl, python could have been used easily and are already installed. I also don't see why someone would need a gui (i see js & jquery - another big lump of code). i7z (cli) and the i7z-gui should be separate installs IMO if they have to have a gui.

Answer (score 34):

1. install the small package of [acpi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/acpi) [image: Install acpi] by this command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install acpi
   ```
2. You will need to press Y for confirmation for the first time.
   Now to find temperature  type this command

   ```
   acpi -t
   ```

Comment: This is simpler than the answers about `lm-sensors`. Could you explain the difference between `acpi` and `lm-sensors`?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, Skylake Laptop, `acpi -t` outputs nothing. It's a valid option, just doesn't work--version: `acpi 1.7`.

Comment: I successfully used `acpi -t` on *grml* live CD system to monitor the temperature of each die of an Core i3 processor. `lm-sensors` isn't preinstalled on *grml* and I can't install other packages there. https://grml.org/

Comment: `acpi` just fails with `No support for device type: power_supply` for me.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, return an empty result.

Answer (score 25):

#### XSensors

XSensors reads data from the libsensors library regarding hardware health such as temperature, voltage and fan speed and displays the information in a digital read-out.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install xsensors lm-sensors
```

Then detect your computer's hardware sensors by opening the terminal and running the command:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect. It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

[image: XSensors Screenshot]

#### Xsensors vs. Psensor

XSensors and Psensor both monitor the computer's temperature and the fan speeds. The difference between the two applications is in the level of detail of the information that is displayed and how the information is displayed.

XSensors displays a little bit more specific information than Psensor. Psensor is smaller and more unobtrusive than XSensors and it displays itself on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures.

Setting up Psensor to detect your computer's hardware is done the same way as Xsensors, by installing lm-sensors to detect your computer's hardware sensors. Then detect your computer's hardware sensors running the command:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

and as with Xsensors, accept the default answers to all questions.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Psensor detects your computer's hardware sensors automatically without running `sudo sensors-detect`

Comment: Psensor seems to be more advanced

Comment: I agree, @Serge.  psensor is the one I am going to use.

Comment: I also use Psensor.

Answer (score 13):

On Raspberry Pi, you can retrieve the temperatureusing `vcgencmd`:

```
vcgencmd measure_temp
```

**Output:**

```
temp=39.0'C
```

Comment: No, that will give you the frequency. Use `vcgencmd measure_temp`

Comment: Sorry, a very painful copy & paste mistake :)

Comment: Is there a way to install this on other distros besides Raspbian? For example, Ubuntu Server 19.10 is available for Raspberry Pi, but I'm not aware of how make this command available.

Answer (score 10):

Just so you guys know, none of this install junk like `sensors` are needed. Just do an `acpi -V` and BOOM, you got everything. Example:

```
Battery 0: Charging, 91%, 00:17:25 until charged
Battery 0: design capacity 3310 mAh, last full capacity 3309 mAh = 99%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 40.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode hot at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: pkg-temp-0 no state information available
Cooling 1: LCD 0 of 100
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

WAY easier than installing all of this and kmod... Just do acpi -V.

Comment: Right… because you don’t have to install that one? Wrong! `The program 'acpi' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install acpi`

Comment: And, it also doesn't always give the same information. On my machine, `sensors` provides the temperature whereas `acpi -V` doesn't show anything about it, unfortunately.

Comment: `acpi -V` is broken for Skylake laptop, Ubuntu 16.04, acpi version 1.7

Answer (score 10):

If you like Python, you can use `psutil`.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()['coretemp']
[shwtemp(label='Physical id 0', current=67.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=67.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=65.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0)]
```

... will do the job. With a little coding, you can for example obtain the Temp vs CPU of your system.

[image]

It's convenient to update `psutil` by issuing `sudo pip3 install psutil --upgrade`.

Comment: I have it on Python 2 but it doesn't have a `sensors_temperatures` attribute, and I don't have it on Python 3. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. So how do I get it?

Comment: what version of psutil are you using? mine is 5.4.3. Try upgrading you version: `sudo pip2 install psutil --upgrade`.

Comment: I'm using 1.2.1 on Python 2, and the upgrade fails (but Python 2 on 14.04 is really outdated, so I'm not concerned). I just installed 5.4.3 on Python 3 with `sudo pip3 install psutil --upgrade`. Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: On that plot, the x-axis is CPU usage, right?

Comment: Done the update of the answer. Yes, the X axis is CPU usgae: I'm having trouble with a laptop: is heating a lot (+65°C) with very low CPU (aprox 5%)

Comment: great answer (+1) - psutil is a gem. It is  ashame it does not cover the HDD temperature

Comment: The only answer that worked. (Ubuntu 20.04) And almost the only one that didn't require installing anything.

Comment: Didn't work for me: `psutil.sensors_temperatures()` returns `{}`.

Answer (score 10):

All bash:

```
getTemp () {
  for zone in `ls /sys/class/thermal/ | grep thermal_zone`
  do
    echo -n "`cat /sys/class/thermal/$zone/type`: "
    echo `cat /sys/class/thermal/$zone/temp | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'`
  done
}

getProcesses() {
  top -b -n 1 | head -n 12  | tail -n 6
}

update () {
  while :
  do
    clear
    getTemp
    echo -e "\nTop 5 CPU hogs:"
    getProcesses
    sleep 5
  done
}


update
```

Comment: It's actually a pretty good script.

Comment: This worked very well!

Answer (score 7):

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

this file holds cpu temperature.
 So, you can make a script named `temp` and move it to `/bin` then in terminal enter `temp`.

My `temp` file looks like -

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cpu_temp=$(< /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
 cpu_temp=$(($cpu_temp/1000))
 echo $cpu_temp°C
```

my answer is modified of [www.cyberciti.biz](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-out-raspberry-pi-gpu-and-arm-cpu-temperature-command/)

Comment: I've tried 4 machines in different locations and they all give the same reading = 27800.  Do you know why this could be? They can't all have the same cpu temp.

Comment: @Katu I think that might mean 27.8 degrees. I used another program and found my Core 0 was 49 C. Then I did the above command and got 49000.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 using Ryzen 7 says: `No data available`.

Answer (score 4):

And here's my 2-cents on this matter. There's `tmon`, a very simple tool that reads the temperature while running another process, just like `time`, `watch`, `timeout`, etc...
`tmon` is a thin wrapper around `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`, and can be useful when monitoring the temperature of your Linux computer/server while running CPU intensive processes: simulation, gaming, etc...

You can download the .AppImage "binary" from here: https://github.com/gmagno/tmon/releases and run it immediately and conveniently, that is:

## Install

```
wget https://github.com/gmagno/tmon/releases/download/v0.3.7/tmon-a461481-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x tmon*.AppImage
# optional: you may put it somewhere convenient in your file system and add a symlink in /usr/local/bin/tmon
```

or if you prefer:

```
pip install tmonpy
```

## Usage

```
./tmon*.AppImage -h
```

## Examples

```
./tmon*.AppImage echo "Quick programs return a single value of temperature"
Quick programs return a single value of temperature


===================
Temp Monitor Report:

   Temp (°C) for a period of 0:00:00
   >> 58.0 °C <<

   /tmp/tmon-20200207@16h07m05-znn0x1o9.txt
===================
```

```
./tmon*.AppImage bash -c 'echo not so quick ones will show a chart; sleep 6'
not so quick ones will show a chart


===================
Temp Monitor Report:

   Temp (°C) for a period of 0:00:06
   60.00  ┤
   59.86  ┤
   59.71  ┤
   59.57  ┤
   59.43  ┤
   59.29  ┤
   59.14  ┤
   59.00  ┼╮   ╭─
   58.86  ┤│   │
   58.71  ┤│   │
   58.57  ┤│   │
   58.43  ┤│   │
   58.29  ┤│   │
   58.14  ┤│   │
   58.00  ┤╰───╯

   >> min: 58.0 °C <<
   >> avg: 58.4 °C <<
   >> max: 59.0 °C <<

   /tmp/tmon-20200207@16h08m25-p010ojhq.txt
===================
```

you may also just run `tmon` without any arguments and it will run as you'd expect. Press Ctrl-C to terminate the process and get a temperature report

```
./tmon*.AppImage  # and wait a few seconds before pressing Ctrl-C
^C

===================
Temp Monitor Report:

   Temp (°C) for a period of 0:00:08
   60.00  ┤
   59.71  ┤
   59.43  ┤
   59.14  ┤
   58.86  ┤  ╭╮
   58.57  ┤  ││
   58.29  ┤  ││
   58.00  ┼╮╭╯│
   57.71  ┤││ │
   57.43  ┤││ │
   57.14  ┤││ │
   56.86  ┤╰╯ │
   56.57  ┤   │
   56.29  ┤   │
   56.00  ┤   ╰────

   >> min: 56.0 °C <<
   >> avg: 56.9 °C <<
   >> max: 59.0 °C <<

   /tmp/tmon-20200207@15h59m37-u4cd94qh.txt
===================
```

Answer (score 4):

One can also use `bpytop`. Install with:

```bsh
sudo snap install bpytop
```

A more powerful version than `htop`, with CPU temperature and much more.

Comment: Wow, you were NOT kidding! I thought I was going into hyperspace when I first saw that loading screen :)

Answer (score 3):

For **Intel CPUs** only You can use `i7z`.

> i7z - A better i7 (and now i3, i5) reporting tool for Linux.

Install it :

```
sudo apt install i7z
```

Then run it (it has to be run with `sudo`):

```
sudo i7z
```

Example output (see `Temp` column - scroll right...):

```
Real Current Frequency 4883.47 MHz [99.98 x 48.85] (Max of below)
    Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp      VCore
    Core 1 [0]:       4883.47 (48.85x)      10.4    73.7    1.45    12.8    47      1.3547
    Core 2 [1]:       4871.56 (48.73x)      8.65    76.8     1.5    11.7    45      1.3547
    Core 3 [2]:       4877.61 (48.79x)      12.2    75.1       1    9.72    52      1.3547
    Core 4 [3]:       4880.70 (48.82x)      7.57    79.7       1    10.5    47      1.3547
```

Answer (score 2):

[computertemp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/computertemp) [image: Install computertemp] is a simple applet that shows your current CPU temperature + it has some additional features like alarms. Unfortunately it's not possible (or at least I don't know how) to change its background color, so it doesn't look very nice with the standard Ubuntu theme.

It can be installed the same way as the sensors-applet described in [evgeny's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/15834#15834).

[image]

computertemp is not available in the newer Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: in Ubuntu 15.04 `sudo apt-get install computertemp` results in the error "Unable to locate package computertemp" ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu with MATE Desktop Environment, you can use MATE Sensors Applet:

1. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-sensors-applet
   ```

   And if you have Nvidia graphics card you can also install `mate-sensors-applet-nvidia` package.
2. Make right click on MATE Panel and click *Add to Panel* then choose **Hardware Sensors Monitor**

   [image: Hardware Sensors Monitor]
3. After adding you can setup it by doing right click on any sensor and selecting *Preferences*

   [image: Preferences Hardware Sensors Monitor]

   Here you can customize the list of sensors: CPU, Motherboard and GPU temperature, main voltages (Vcore, 3.3V, 5V, 12V, etc) and fan speeds. The full list depends on hardware (image above is for desktop with Nvidia graphics card).
4. The result will look like

   [image: Sensors]

Of course you can move this applet to the best location.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different places you might find the temperature listed in millidegrees. I finally found mine here:

```
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp*_input
```

Here are some other places users have reported to have found their temperature

```
/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/temperature
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/temp
/sys/devices/platform/f71882fg.1152/temp*_input
/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*/temp*_input
```

Some of these are just symbolic links to the others. You may have to look carefully to find it

Comment: it was at `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*/temp*_input` on my Dell Precision M4800

Comment: Neither path works for an AMD Ryzen CPU.

Comment: @momo2047 If you find it, let me know where, and I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

GUI alternatives for `sensors` command are [Psensor](http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/) and XSensors:

```
sudo apt install xsensors
sudo apt install psensor
```

For better detection of your hardware's sensors, you can also run following:

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
sensors
watch -d -n 1 sensors
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%d°\n' $(sensors | grep 'id 0:' | awk '{ print $4 }') 2>/dev/null
55°
```

printf '%d\n' Will convert the value to integer in case you need it as a round number

---

*Sources: [Linuxhacks.org](https://linuxhacks.org/how-to-get-the-cpu-temperature/)

Disclosure: I am the owner of Linuxhacks.org*

Comment: Why `echo $(printf ..)` and not just `printf '%d°\n'  $(sensors | grep 'id 0:' | awk '{ print $4 }') 2>/dev/null`? ... Or even just `sensors 2>/dev/null | awk '/id 0:/{printf "%d°\n", $4}'`

Comment: Yes, a lot of possibility, i just posted the one i was using