# How to get fancontrol running?

Tags: fan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working)

I am using fancontrol to make sure that nothing makes more noise than necessary. But since I updated to Oneiric it does not work anymore. The problem is, that the hwmon devices changes any time I boot my machine, so that I have to run pwmconfig any time to get a new configuration file for fancontrol. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Read this forum. It seems to be solved:
[FanControl Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Comment: @htorque you are right. I'll take your comment under consideration from now on. Thanks for your advise.