# Problem with pwmconfig - can't control CPU fan

Tags: asus, fan, cpu, sensors, modules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working)

On Windows 7 I can set CPU fan speed via ASUS software that was included on CD. I tried to set CPU fan also on Ubuntu and I found this: http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/127/how-to-control-fan-speed-lm-sensors-in-ubuntu . I installed **lm-sensors** and I ran **sudo sensors-detect** (here's ending output):

```
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `it87':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `ITE IT8728F Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 10h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `sbs':
  * Bus `Radeon i2c bit bus 0x92'
    Busdriver `UNKNOWN', I2C address 0x0b
    Chip `Smart Battery' (confidence: 5)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
it87
sbs
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)no

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Then I run **sudo sensors -s** (no output) and **sudo sensors**:

```
$ sudo sensors
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:      +1.39 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:      +3.36 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:        +5.13 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:      +10.41 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:     4623 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed: 4623 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CPU Temperature:    +49.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
MB Temperature:     +43.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +75.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +49.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +83.5°C, hyst = +81.5°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +67.5°C
```

Finally I ran **sudo pwmconfig**:

```
$ sudo pwmconfig 
# pwmconfig revision 5857 (2010-08-22)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

What is going on? Why pwmconfig does not detect modules? My **/etc/modules** file:

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc

# Generated by sensors-detect on Mon Dec 26 10:35:41 2011
# Chip drivers
it87
sbs
```

My system and hardware info:

```
$ inxi -F
System:    Host: area51 Kernel: 3.0.0-15-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: M5A78L-M/USB3 version: Rev X.0x Bios: American Megatrends version: 0411 date: 08/11/2011
CPU:       Quad core AMD Phenom II X4 955 (-MCP-) cache: 2048 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4a svm) 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 3200.00 MHz 2: 3200.00 MHz 3: 3200.00 MHz 4: 3200.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: ATI Barts PRO [ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series] 
           X.Org: 1.10.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: vesa,fbdev) Resolution: 1440x900@59.9hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD BARTS GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 7.11
Audio:     Card-1: ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) driver: HDA Intel Sound: ALSA ver: 1.0.24
           Card-2: ATI Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series] driver: HDA Intel
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller driver: r8168 
           IF: eth1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 54:04:a6:15:11:77
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 484.3GB (6.4% used) 1: /dev/sda SAMSUNG_SP1654N 160.0GB 
           2: /dev/sdb SAMSUNG_HM320JI 320.1GB 3: USB /dev/sdc Flash_Disk 4.2GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 19G used: 5.2G (30%) fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 127G used: 23G (19%) fs: ext4 
           ID: swap-1 size: 2.04GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: 43.0C gpu: 67.5 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 4560 sys-1: 4560 
Info:      Processes: 216 Uptime: 22 min Memory: 2895.7/8000.2MB Client: Shell inxi: 1.7.27
```

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Come on, nobody knows?...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working