# Bumblebee Overheating

Tags: bumblebee

My laptop Samsung RF411(Geforce 540M) is overheating when i run `optirun glxspheres` the temperature of the core jumps to 97C and the GPU to 72C and after some minuties the computer shutdown.

An strange thing is that the GPU in Windows goes 84C and the core stays in 86C. I think that should be a problem in controlling the fan speed.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-25-generic and the drive of nvidia is 302.17.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is the solutions to all Optimus problems.

Answer (score 4):

As you said, the problem must be on the fan control. When I use `optirun glxgspheres` on my system it takes almost 100% of CPU, which is strange. Running with integrated card or with `primusrun` the cpu usage stays at ~25%. If you use Bumblebee frequently you can try to play with `VGLTransport` value in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` or using Primus.

But the problem should reside on all applications using a lot of CPU, and not in Bumblebee in special.

There are a lot of questions already posted here on how to control fan speed, so check them out and see if any solves your problem. Some examples:

- [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working)
- [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Only installing the new beta version of Nvidia 319.12 with bumblebee that i could solve my problem.

> sudo apt-get remove bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-current nvidia-settings
>
> sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319

Link http://orkultus.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/how-to-nvidia-319-12-drivers-in-ubuntu-based-systems-with-bumblebee/