# ubuntu 12.10 very high temprature on idle

Tags: 12.10, ati, intel, temperature

I upgraded my laptop to ubuntu 12.10 and my laptop temperature went extremely high. It's over 80 degrees Celcius on idle and it can easily go to 87C with just a little browsing. On 90C my laptop shuts down. I am pretty sure it's 12.10 problem because I didn't have this problem with previous releases. Also, I have dual boot with windows Vista and when I boot it, the temps are normal.

My CPU is Intel Core 2 Duo T8300 and my GPU is Ati Mobility Radeon X2300

Any suggestions?

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to check how big SWAP partition do you have. I can see that you have quite strong machine, and I assume that you have a good amount of RAM memory - so you do not need a lot of SWAP space. Having big SWAP partition (i.e. 2-3GB) allows system to use hard drive as RAM memory, so your HDD works even if you don't actually access any files on HDD at the moment. 
Unfortunately Ubuntu assign to much SWAP space in my opinion during automate installation in my case Ubuntu took 2GB from 160GB HDD. having 4GB RAM memory I think, that 256-512MB is enough (my friend having 8GB RAM machine use no SWAP)
I think that can be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For most hardware there should only be two ways in which software can affect its temperature:

1. It overloads it by running it close to 100% for a long time. (Should not apply to good hardware)
2. It winds down active cooling (i.e. fan speed)

If it's 1, then you should consult the manufacturer of your hardware.

For 2 I suggest that you have a look at [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working) and make sure that fan speed is turned up.