# Constant fan spinning

Tags: dell, fan

Almost every action I initiate, like opening the terminal or clicking a menu, makes the fan start spinning. That did not happen on Windows, for instance.

And it doesn't seem normal, so how can I make sure that my system is running fine? Can I somehow fix this abnormal fan function?

I'm running ubuntu 12.10 64-bit on a dell laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=958894). Should be a good starting point. And of course, the usual advise applies: Have you made sure your fan is "clean" enough (dust etc.)?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The fan is clean; on Windows this issue isn't happening.