# fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory|

Tags: 14.04, libraries, c

It has been weeks that I am trying to use Code::Blocks IDE on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to program Atmega16, however I am hindered by the following error while compiling/building the program in C::B

```
/usr/include/features.h|374|fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory|
```

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303037/cannot-compile-simple-c-program-in-ubuntu)
and based on that I have tried to purge `libc6-dev` and ran into trouble by removing the dependencies. From previous experience I knew that there is a huge probability to get into broken pipe error. I tackled it by installing the lost dependencies.

Now still I have the same error.

Answer (score 174):

If you are on an amd64 installation, you can try to install the package `libc6-dev-i386`. This helped me solve the same issue you encountered while [trying to compile](https://askubuntu.com/a/418000) smm from i8kutils.

Comment: This worked like a charm. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Might be better to install gcc-multilib and g++-multilib.

Comment: Installing libc6 and libc6-dev solved it for me. I had also found some reference for it, but sadly i lost it.

Comment: libc6-dev-i386 is one of the additional packages will be installed if i run `sudo apt-get install g++-multilib` in Kali 2016.2.

Comment: @RobotHumans, installing `gcc-multilib` wants to remove my `gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi` and doesn't seem to install anything actually replacing it. So that doesn't look like a good idea. Sorry.

Comment: If you have many compiler toolchains, that would seem like a packaging bug.  The multilib one gets you 32 and 64 bit builders, but probably says something silly like remove all other toolchains first to try and prevent conflicts.  Worked for me, but I did not have compilers for arm.  I use VMs for that.

Answer (score 52):

On my machine, where I've probably screwed around too much with 32 and 64 bit architecture files, I resolved this issue by installing `g++-multilib`.

Answer (score 4):

Typing the command:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6 libc6-dev
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to askubuntu! Please use the guideline of https://askubuntu.com/editing-help to format your posts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1050917/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**  (CC @abu_bua )

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an Ubuntu-centric branch of  but this page is the first one that came up when I searched this error on Google (even when I put -Ubuntu in the search), so I'm going to share my answer for Arch linux here:

In Arch, I got a /lib/cpp fail sanity check because the package glibc was corrupt and missing all the /usr/include/sys headers. I resolved this error by recompling glibc.

Comment: Funny, I resolved this problem a couple of months ago and I completely forgot about it. So here I was looking for a solution again. Thank god for this site. :)

Comment: That comment :) I have heard that sites in Stack Exchange overall have done this plenty of times before

Comment: This was killing me, fresh install of Arch and I couldn't build anything. I check and `/usr/include/sys` is totally empty! Reinstalled glibc and everything is perfect. Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like **sys/cdefs.h** is defined under `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys`, but `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` is **NOT** a default **INCLUDE_PATH**.

Answer (score 1):

`apt install gcc-multilib` will also install the library you need `libc6-dev-i386` along with packages you might need in future.

Answer (score 0):

I got this while trying to compile openssl-1.0.2a while chrooted to a wheezy 32-bit partition while running a 64-bit kernel. the "./config" script was too smart, and decided to configure for amd64. I solved it by `MACHINE=i386 ./config --prefix=$HOME`, and then `make` worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this by accidently adding the `-m32` option (gcc told me to add for `-maes` but it was wrong).