# Notebook keyboard gets hot only on the left side!

Tags: laptop, power-management, fan, fancontrol, heat

I have the Asus VivoBook S551lb, a thin notebook, with intel i7 4500u 1.8 ghz , intel 4600m internal graphics, and nvidia 740m discrete graphics.

It looks like the fan placed in the left side , after time using ubuntu 14.04 my keyboard get hot ONLY FROM THE LEFT SIDE (not very hot about 50c to 60c) , the side of WSAD keys , the top right side (numbers ) is COLD and i mean COLD .

the pc is usable but why its warm only in the left side ! is it a problem ?

Output from `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:        +50.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

Comment: Welcome! As a start, can you try  `sensors-detect` and `sensors` ? It may show the internal temprature measurements.

Comment: Did you run it with a different system earlier and it did not get hot?

Comment: Regarding the downvotes: I think it may be about the fan control not working, which would be a valid question.

Comment: The asus s551lb is a thin laptop. How is the other computer relevant? That's a desktop, right?

Comment: i used windows 8.1 64bit , i get a lil bit hotter than ubuntu 14.04 64bit but i dont remember win8.1 get hot only in the left side !

Comment: i followed sensors-detect then sensors

Comment: You can edit your question to append it (as answer it will get deleted)

Comment: Hmm... there are measurements, but seem odd, all about 50 deg.

Comment: yeah i think the fans working , as asus say the fans are really quite , even me i dont hear any thing exept some times the hard drive . but its much odd to get hot in the side where placed the fans

Comment: Even if you do not hear them, you would find warm air coming out somewhere - can you check?

Comment: no there is not warm air coming out from any side , even in the bottom there is a place where pushing out hot air from the fans but its not pushing out any thing ( sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working

Comment: i took a look and i tried pwmconfig and it said /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed
i tried fancontrol and it said Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
 im not sure its an "overheating" problem because the pc is usable , i want to know if its normal to have a warm side and a cold side because i dont remeber i get such problem with windows 8.1 (the whole pc get hot a lil bit more than ubuntu not only the left side )

Comment: Yes, you did not say id overheats, it was my assumption. But please clarify in the question what devices we are talkin about. There is a notebook, and PC, and both get hot?

Comment: i only talk about my notebook asus s551lb , i7 4500u , intel 4600m , nvidia 740m 2gb , 6 gb ram

Comment: i talk about the same laptop when i speak about windows 8.1 get the pc (my asus s551lb) hot all over not only the left side like ubuntu in the same pc (aus s551lb)

Comment: Ok, now I got it, sorry. I had read your hardware description as That asus notebook (that I looked up) with i7 4500u CPU plus something else, because I thought `intel 4600m` is a second CPU in a second device. But what is it?

Comment: ah sorry it was not clear , intel 4600m HD is the integrated graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Surface temperature

The question is about an unusual surface temperatue distribution on the body of a very thin notebook. It basically asks "Is that normal?"

#### Misconfigured?

I took the question as describing side effects of misconfigured fan- or power saving configuration.
I tried pretty hard to find that implied problem, but finally gave up.

### Is it normal

A misconfiguration would lead to an answer "No, it's not normal" - but this does not seem to be the problem.

So, let's take it literally - is it normal that the  left side of the case is much warmer than right?

A relevant information is that it's a very thin notebook, the Asus VivoBook S551lb. It is relatively difficult to get heat out of a thin device.
So, let's take a look what is inside on the left side - maybe there's just something related to heat?

In [this review of the S551lb](http://www.ultrabookreview.com/3084-asus-vivobook-s551-review/) there are some images of the opened device.

This image [shows of the uncovered bottom side](http://www.ultrabookreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/asus-s551-hardware.jpg), with keyboard pointing down. We can see a copper heatpipe, ending between fan and air exhaust, and starting from a large heat spreader at the right. The component under that is probably the CPU, but could also be the graphics processor.  But that's irrelevant - what we know it that it's the component that produces the most heat.

### Yes, normal!

Now, the solution is easy: turning the device around, the hot component goes to the left;
Is it normal that the case is most hot near the hottest component? Yes.
Looking at the components on the right side, there is mainly a CD drive and the hdd. Both do not get hot, so it's also normal that the right side is relatively cool.

An interesting aspect is that the device has a metal body, probably made of some aluminium alloy - a good heat conductor.
When you touch the surface to tell the temparature, the metal can transport a lot of heat energy from or into your finger in a short time. That makes you feel the temperature much more pronounced compared to the same temperature on a surface of some plastics or wood with much lower heat conduction.

And that is quite relevant to the question: As far as I know, touching aluminium alloy at 60°C would hurt quite badly. So we can now assume that the actual temparature was much lower;
That means that the reason that made me expect a fan/power misconfiguration did not exist in the first place.

See also this [review with nice thermal imaging pictures](http://www.digitalversus.com/laptop/asus-vivobook-s551lb-p17333/test.html)  of the device.