# Dell Vostro 3560 overheats and fan is quiet and it's speed is low

Tags: ati, 14.10, overheating, fan, dell-vostro

After enabling discrete Radeon HD 7600M on my Dell Vostro 3560 I've faced with overheating problem. Fan control doesn't work. To be precise fan speed is being constantly lowered to 135000 rpm.
I've updated BIOS to A17 version. I've set up i8kmon according to [this](http://keenformatics.blogspot.it/2013/06/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in.html). I've also disabled BIOS fan control via SMM registers according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working/398635#398635). Nothing helps.

After issuing `i8kctl fan -1 2` fan speed rises up to 178000 rpm and slowly lowered to 135000 rpm within a few seconds. CPU temp is still about 93°C. I don't care of fan noise but I do care of overheating and poweroffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that **dust** is the reason. After disassembling (video guides can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=dell%20vostro%203560%20ac%20dc%20power%20jack%20repair)) and cleaning with dust blowing ball I see about 60°-65°C on all cores.