# Dell Inspiron and i8kutils

Tags: dell, overheating, fan, fancontrol

I've been trying to get i8kutils working with my Dell 15-5000, but to no avail. I've followed the instructions posted on [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working) to try and disable the BIOS thermal control, but it still keeps overriding i8k after a few seconds. I've read on several places that you can access the thermal control config with FN+1,5,3,2,4 -> FN+R, but that hasn't worked for me either.