# Old Toshiba shuts down while running make

Tags: shutdown, toshiba

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my old Toshiba Satellite A75, completely replacing Windows XP. The good news is that ubuntu changed this laptop from a doorstop to a nice machine for software development. The bad news is that it may not be nice enough. While running "make" to build a version of Audacity, it shuts off suddenly and completely, as if I held the power button down. It boots back up OK, but I have to run "make clean" and start the make over again because of the partial .o files left by the shut-down. I thought this might be due to overheating, but I am not sure. It also happened when I was watching a YouTube video in full screen mode. I checked the power settings and the system is set not to hibernate due to inactivity. Any ideas out there? Thanks.

Warren

Comment: Looks like it shuts down when under load, which makes overheating plausible. Try watching the CPU temp. Here is [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature) to help you with it. Adding the hardware specs wouldn't be a bad idea as well.

Comment: I use 'Psensor' to monitor temps on my new laptop.

Comment: Thanks, but my laptop apparently does not have the necessary sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the fans, when you do make, it puts load on CPU thereby increasing the heat. Also see if they have a BIOS update for your laptop.