# Intel Turbo boost on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, intel

Well, I have a Toshiba laptop with an Intel i5 2430m and 4 gb ram installed. I have  intalled the i-Nex so to know my cpu frequency at every time. But there is a problem: Even when I'm editing a video, the cpu runs at 2.4Gh with 80-100% cpu load! But the intel turbo boost technology does not get enabled, while when i was using windows, these things were happening automatically! 
So, how can i enable the Turbo feature? *This feature is enabled in bios settings*

Edit: I Think that this could help, but i'm not so sure: [CPU Turbo boost: modify temperature limit under 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457597/cpu-turbo-boost-modify-temperature-limit-under-14-04)

Comment: Have a look at this thread [Intel Turboboost](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247549).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you know what you are talking about, because you describe something that is very different from [how this technology was initially supposed to work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost#Example).

## Turbo Boost, glitter for standard clock speed

Turbo boost will not automatically overclock your CPU if both of your cores are already constantly at 80-100% load. Some later variations (depending on the CPU model) will boost under full load for very short intervals to then cool down with negligible long term performance impact. All in all you won't achieve a constant overclocking boost, because as I said, this is not how this feature is designed.

## Themal design and cooling

Also one should first provide a better cooling solution before trying to mess with the  thermal thresholds that the system designers and engineers carefully defined during the product development. In general, you should never even think about modifying temperature limit for laptops (as the other question initially asked for).

## Possible traps: the wrong monitoring tool

There was some confusion when Turbo Boost was introduced, because some tools that monitored the frequency and/or changed governors interfered with Turbo Boost and prevented it from properly working.

> Some hardware monitoring applications or panel-applets that allow to display or modify processor clock speeds bring disorder into the fragile arrangement, hence one should stay away from these when in doubt [if turbo boost is working correctly].

Original citation in German:

> Einige Hardware-Monitoring-Programme oder Panel-Applets zur Anzeige
>   oder Konfiguration der Prozessor-Taktstufen bringen dies fragile
>   Gefüge aber durcheinander, daher lässt man von diesen im Zweifel
>   besser die Finger.

<sup>Heise: [Turbo Boost unter Linux](http://heise.de/-861189) (probably better known for its English site [The H](http://www.h-online.com/))</sup>

## Conlusion

While you can try the link (which is not about Turbo Boost but P-States, which is more technical and about power management) posted in an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/457893/40581) on the other question, you have to realize **Turbo Boost is not about constant overclocking under constant heavy load, but improving performance for short bursts**, which won't reduce workloads like video editing *significantly*.

Also you have to realize that marketing (deliberately conf-)uses higher specs that are only achieved in certain boost conditions (or sometimes never, like on some ultrabooks), instead of the standard clock speeds. (This is not very new, the Pentium 4 processors have been known for clocking lower due to overheating, it just got more complicated and made its way to graphics cards, tablet and smartphone processors.)

Simply speaking, if you bought a product with a [2 core CPU at a clock speed of 2.4 GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/53450/Intel-Core-i5-2430M-Processor-%283M-Cache-2_40-GHz%29) and thought you get a 4 core CPU with 3 GHz clock speed or something in between, then realize that you have been fooled or the one who sold you the product didn't know any better.

Comment: hahaha! First, thank you very much for your answer! I really appreciate that :D ! But now, you have to understand something else: It is true that I didn't know these facts about turbo boost, but believe me, i do know what I bought and what I could do with this machine! In any way, please, not be so rude in your next answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the terminology wrong. You may have meant to refer to Intel EIST, which is what reduces clock speed when idle, or C1E, which is what reduces voltage. Turbo Boost is what boosts core speed above 2.4GHz when the CPU is under heavy use, though the reachable speed depends on temperature and how many cores are in use.

In your BIOS, you should enable all three: Enable Intel EIST so the CPU speed drops when the CPU is idle, enable Intel C1E so it uses less current as well when idle, and enable Turbo Boost so when you are using it, the CPU speed can go above 2.4GHz.

You do not need to do anything to Ubuntu to take advantage of any of these features.  Ubuntu sends all the proper signals to the CPU, telling it when it's idle and when to ramp up clock speed, to allow these features to work, and you do not have to adjust any of this.