# how to control CPU frequency in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, overheating, frequency

how to control CPU frequency in 14.04? juipiter and cpu-freq cannot be installed due to bugs.. Kindly help.. the pc in boiling..

Comment: "how to control CPU frequency in 14.04?"  With cpu-frequtils/cpufreqd. I believe you should focus on the bug related to this program. It is in the default repo's so I doubt it is as faulty that it does not install nor give no information about your bug.

Comment: @Rinzwind, note that cpufreqd is obsolete and no longer maintained so its use should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Source:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/457597/cpu-turbo-boost-modify-temperature-limit-under-14-04
```

Please consider reading that article answer.

Intel Overheating:

```
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html
```

This worked for me

Good luck!

Comment: Here is the same link, clickable: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457597/cpu-turbo-boost-modify-temperature-limit-under-14-04