# Undo whatever lm-sensors has done

Tags: temperature, lm-sensors

I have accepted all the 'risky' things `lm-sensors` wanted to do with my system since [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/15833/134848) told me so. My computer is now getting a lot hotter than before, even outside of Ubuntu, and I think it is due to that.

How to undo whatever changes `lm-sensors` has made to my system?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall lm-sensors and its dependencies

```
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove lm-sensors
```

Purging your config/data too

```
   sudo apt-get purge lm-sensors
```

Comment: The problems are also outside of Ubuntu so I don't think this undoes everything.

Comment: I do not know if `lm-sensor` can change something at the NVRAM (Bios) level. In that case only a full BIOS reset can return the system to its previous state. How to do that depend on the specific computer/bios.