# Could sensors-detect have done anything bad to my machine

Tags: hardware, lm-sensors

I recently installed `lm-sensors` and ran the command (as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/628117/364819)):

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

But then I read the `man` page on it which said:

```
DESCRIPTION
       sensors-detect is an interactive program that will walk you through the process of scanning your system for various hardware monitor‐
       ing chips, or sensors, supported by libsensors(3), or more generally by the lm_sensors tool suite.

       sensors-detect will look for the following devices, in order:

       ·      Sensors embedded in CPUs, south bridges and memory controllers.

       ·      Sensors embedded in Super I/O chips.

       ·      Hardware monitoring chips accessed through ISA I/O ports.

       ·      Hardware monitoring chips reachable over the SMBus or more generally any I2C bus on your system.

       As the last two detection steps can cause trouble on some systems, they are normally not attempted if the second detection  step  led
       to  the  discovery  of  a Super I/O chip with complete hardware monitoring features.  However, the user is always free to ask for all
       detection steps if so is his/her wish. This can be useful if a given system has more than one hardware monitoring chip. Some  vendors
       are known to do this, most notably Asus and Tyan.
```

And:

```
WARNING
       sensors-detect needs to access the hardware for most of the chip detections.  By definition, it doesn't know which  chips  are  there
       before  it  manages  to identify them. This means that it can access chips in a way these chips do not like, causing problems ranging
       from SMBus lockup to permanent hardware damage (a rare case, thankfully.)

       The authors made their best to make the detection as safe as possible, and it turns out to work just fine in most cases,  however  it
       is  impossible  to  guarantee that sensors-detect will not lock or kill a specific system. So, as a rule of thumb, you should not run
       sensors-detect on production servers, and you should not run sensors-detect if can't afford replacing a random part of  your  system.
       Also, it is recommended to not force a detection step which would have been skipped by default, unless you know what you are doing.
```

But as I had not really been warning when I was running the first last part, I ran it, and the result was:

```
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No
```

Although the second last part properly warned me so I did not run it. But the fact that it says `No` for the first last one, does this mean anything, or is there any way of telling at all (other than waiting) whether any damage was done to my system? Would the program have indicated at all if something bad had happened? Or is there any way of checking?

I have got a Lenovo B590.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: No simply means it didn't find any supported sensors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears running the last part of sensors-detect can overwrite values in an EPROM controlling the LCD display on some laptops. If your display looks fine there is no damage.

See [Archwiki sensors-detect discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193048&p=1) for more details.