# Making an request/command in terminal (ubuntu) and save the answer in mysql

Tags: command-line, mysql

I am looking for a batch to make little commands in a terminal (for ubuntu) and save the answers in a data base in mysql in the same computer.

For example, I want to ask the temperature of the computer each hour, and save the answers in a data base already created. I do not if I should use php or just a batch to make a connection to the data base and save the information,  but I do not know how to do neither of this posibilities.

Help please.

Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done in Python. First, learn how to get your CPU's temperature [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature). Either use the `sensors` command or the `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` to write the current temperature to a temporary file `curr.temperature`. You can do that seperately in a bash script or in the Python program itself, using:

```py
from subprocess import call
call (["/path/to/script/get_temperature"], shell=False)
```

Then the Python code just needs to read the file `curr.temperature` and store the value in a MySQL table. I have not tested this code, but it should be something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb.cursors
with open('curr.temperature', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read() 
db = MySQLdb.connect(db='databasename', host='localhost',
                     port=3306, user='MySQL-username', passwd='password',
                     cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temperatures VALUES (now," + read_data + ")" )
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please click the check mark next to the question to mark the question as "answered".