# My computer reboots randomly

Tags: crash

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 . When using the pc (usually watching a video on youtube, or something that requires some cpu) it reboots, and then it usually doesn't restart again, you have to switch off and wait for some minutes, then switch on and it works, what could happend? I checked memories and hard disc and Ubuntu said they were ok. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your computer is overheating. Is it a laptop? How old is it?

Comment: It is a desktop 64 bits pc, it has 8 years of use... How could I know if it's temperature?

Comment: 8 years? That's a pretty long time. You should open it up and clean out any dust you find (I'm going to bet there's a lot). Also keep it open and turn it on to make sure all the fans are working.

Comment: Use this to see the temps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature

Comment: Thanks, I've made all steps, and it says: temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +124.0°C)

k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp:   +37.0°C  
Core0 Temp:   +22.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +31.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +22.0°C  

Is it right? I will clean inside it.

Comment: Well that looks OK right now. I'd do what you do to make it shut down and monitor those temps at the same time.

Comment: I'm hearing a video on youtube and using a virtual machine, and temperature doesn't get high... Could it be another thing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure. Give it a bit, and definitely clean the computer out.

Comment: I'm here to help :)

Comment: Sorry for annoying again, after some hard use it says temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +124.0°C)

k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp:   +61.0°C  
Core0 Temp:   +62.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +59.0°C  
Core1 Temp:   +61.0°C Is it still right?

Comment: Strange. It's getting higher, but I don't think it's to the point of shutting down. However, I still believe it has something to do with heat, so definitely clean the computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, more than 80º would be dangerous?

Comment: Well, it says the maximum for your CPU is 124˚, but that seems really high. I think 70˚ is pushing it, and 80˚ is definitely bad.

Comment: It may not be the CPU but possibly the PSU because as mentioned it usually doesn't start back up again after it shuts itself down. The first thing I'd do is try a spare PSU for a few days and see if it keeps shutting down.

Comment: Have you checked for BSOD error?

Comment: Its a common issue with unsupported GPU - they overheat and the system shuts down. I have a few old notebooks where i couldnt find a fix except physical measures. All you can try in this case is to load proprietary drivers or use an outdated OS that supports the GPU

Answer (score 1):

There are things that could cause this, one is heat as others have mentioned, and another is the power supply. Open the side of the pc if this is a desktop, and leave it open. Start up the pc. If it stays on, heat is your issue. Try blowing it out with a blower or another less preferred option is to use the vacuum cleaner to remove dust from the heatsink on the cpu.

If this does not solve the problem replace you Power Supply. The fact that it doesn’t come on for a while after the shutdown is making me suspect static in the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo init 6
```

after it restarts see if it is still happening