# My ubuntu 16.04 reboots by itself

Tags: reboot

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and now I'm experiencing that my computer reboots every few hours by itself.
What is the cause of this and how can I fix this?

Comment: We need more information, is it a sudden shutdown, without any loading screens? or does it take it's time. If it's the first one, it is most likely a hardware issue, if it is the second one, ubuntu may be shutting down due to overheating, or an error. if you have a different pc power supply, or laptop battery, you should try using those, good luck, and please give a bit more info.

Comment: I'm seeing hard resets every once in a while. Happens every few hours, usually while I'm doing something heavy-ish or when I log in to x. It actually started right after the last kernel upgrade on the previous version of ubuntu. I figured upgrading might get me a new, unbugged kernel but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

it does a restart every now and then. I'm using a laptop. the laptop does feel very warm sometimes. so I guess it's probably a temperature issue as you mentioned.

Comment: As you said the laptop does feel very warm sometimes. So check its temperature before it reboots, every 5-10 minutes.
here is one nice [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/15833/458673) that may help you.