# Temperature sensors broken?

Tags: drivers, cpu, fan, temperature, sensors

I just followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/15833/425454) to install `lm-sensors` on my machine but the output I get is kind of weird:

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

radeon-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +9.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +8.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +69.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:           N/A  (crit =  25.01 W)
```

My room temperature is around 20 degrees so 9 is definitely not an accurate reading, also I know for a fact that my cpu fan is spinning.

Is it possible that my sensors are broken, it's a brand new motherboard (asus am1m-a). If not what could be the cause of this, I would really like to be able to read my temperatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Asus am1m-a motherboard is really unusual in that it does not have a CPU, a GPU and a supporting chipset, but relies on a complete system being integrated into an APU (a system on a chip). Given this unusual architecture it is not surprising `sensors` struggles.

I suspect its going to be very hard to get sensors to work properly. I would remove `lm-sensors` and trust the advanced UEFI BIOS to look after fan control for you.