# ubuntu 16.04 shuts down after a few minutes

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

Trying to run 16.04 on my Intel I7-6700HQ 4x260GHz, Nvidia GeForce GTX965m. It works fine on 15.10, but when I boot up 16.04 from the USB, the fan (graphics card I think) just starts running and runs full-bore until the machine turns itself off after about a minute. The same thing happened on 14.04. I'm assuming it's something to do with support for the chipset, but since it works in 15.10, I would have assumed it worked in 16.04? Anyone got any experience of this?
I've tried to get it to run the proprietary drivers for both cpu microcode and GPU, but it always shuts down before it can install them. 
I get this message on boot, if that helps:

[image: boot message]

Comment: Looks like your system is detecting a high cputemperature. You could double-check this in BIOS/UEFI - as most modern machines are able to tell temps there as well.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in my bios to check temp. But the weird thing is, it works fine in ubuntu 15.10? That's what I've got installed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out your temperatures on ubuntu 15.10? or if you are able to run 16.04 for a little while check them on there as well.

Way on how to check your temperatures:
[How do I get the CPU temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature)

Comment: The cpu temp in 15.10 is as follows: acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
I can't keep it alive in 16.04 long enough to install the sensor software.