# CPU temperature embedded in Bash command prompt

Tags: bash

I was wondering if it would be possible to obtain the CPU temperature and embed it into the command prompt.

This is my output for `sensors`:

```
$}-sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +52.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Could you please show me how to use the `grep` function to embed the temperature into my command prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the CPU temperature?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature)

Comment: qucik: cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp , for me it shows 50000, when my temperature is 50°C

Comment: @mondjunge those files are very hardware dependent. Both the names and the paths will change depending on what hardware you have. On my system, that file shows the temperature of the `acpitz-virtual-0` virtual device and that is very different from the temperature of my CPU.

Comment: You can use the same code I have in my answer. It will also work for your `sensors` output.

Comment: @terdon: I know but don't have the time to explain, I just mark duplicated questions in my free 5 Minutes and try to hint out a quick solution.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but the details depend on your system. In most cases, the command `sensors` should show it.

1. Install the necessary package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
   ```
2. Run `sensors-detect` and follow the prompts

   ```
   sudo sensors-detect
   ```
3. Install any extra drivers if `sensors-detect` tells you to.
4. Run `sensors` to make sure it works

   ```
   $ sensors
   acpitz-virtual-0
   Adapter: Virtual device
   temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
   temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

   coretemp-isa-0000
   Adapter: ISA adapter
   Physical id 0:  +63.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
   Core 0:         +62.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
   Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

   nct6776-isa-0a00
   Adapter: ISA adapter
   Vcore:                  +1.86 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)  ALARM
   in1:                    +1.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
   AVCC:                   +3.33 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
   +3.3V:                  +3.33 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
   in4:                    +1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
   in5:                    +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
   in6:                    +0.21 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
   3VSB:                   +3.31 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
   Vbat:                   +3.18 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
   fan1:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
   fan2:                  3292 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
   SYSTIN:                  +0.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
   CPUTIN:                 +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = CPU diode
   AUXTIN:                  +0.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = CPU diode
   PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:  +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
   PECI Agent 0:           +60.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                                    (crit = +105.0°C)
   PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
   PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
   intrusion0:            OK
   intrusion1:            OK
   beep_enable:           disabled
   ```
5. Parse the output to get only the CPU temperature.

   As you can see above, the output on my system is different than yours. However, the line we care about here is the same. You can get the CPU temperature with:

   ```
   $ sensors | grep -oP 'Physical.*?\+\K[0-9.]+'
   63.0
   ```
6. Edit your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent file if you're using another shell) and add a function that runs the command above:

   ```
   show_temp(){
       sensors | grep -oP 'Physical.*?\+\K[0-9.]+'
   }
   ```
7. Use the function in your prompt. For example:

   ```
   PS1="\u@\h $(show_temp) $ "
   ```

Comment: Is really necessary to install lm-sensors in Ubuntu? Is installed by default in Debian.

Comment: @Braiam It is not installed by default in 15.10 or 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Install lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Detect what sensors are available:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

To show the temperature:

```
sensors
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP wants the CPU temperature to appear in their Bash prompt, like `username@hostname (cputemp): /current/directory $` - They already know how to run the `sensors` command in general, how would they have been able to show the output in the question otherwise?

Comment: @ByteCommander in Bram's defense, the OP didn't mention `sensors` in their original question and only added the output after I asked for it in the first revision of my answer. Granted, this answer doesn't explain how to show CPU temp only nor how to include it in the prompt, but mentioning `sensors` was useful information when the answer was posted.