# 1997 IBM colossus. Asus IX Hero, Core i7-7700K build management questions

Tags: configuration, intel

I had an iMac with Ubuntu on an Samsung 850 EVO lose interest in life so I kept the drive and went with a more reliable IBM 1997 gutted Think Center smelling of cigarettes. Gee whiz the ATX boards have changed and I had to delete the back panel and all internal hangers. I got a hero9 and screwed it in with cork as spacers for now. Bumped in 32GB of DDR4 Corsair Vengeance RAM. 3200mbps. Corsair h80I v2.  650 watt Corsair power supply. The thing does not get warm. Of course I don't have any game titles to test on it yet. I only emulated PlayStation 2 at 10x native. It did good but my pcsx emulator is choppy. No standalone GPU but I can't imagine that a new i7 with 32GB can't hold its own. I did bump it up to 4.3 GHz in the BIOS, but what software do I have available through Linux and should I upgrade to 17.04? I'm using 16.04 LTS from my iMac.

Comment: Stick with the latest Ubuntu **L**ong **T**erm **S**upport (LTS) release 16.04 at least until you are sure that you have completely finished replacing and testing your computer's hardware. You need a stable release with a long period of support to test your hardware changes with.

Comment: Thanks! By the way... I am on my phone. So It wasn't suposrd to be a compiling tag. I meant to put configuration. I really would like to monitor the temperature. Also not to change the subject but I didn't have this issue until I installed pcsx my refresh rate drops to 24hz. Even after I put it back using terminal. It's there a secret to that?   I even uninstalled pcsx.... My other account is fine its just the admin account...

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the latest Ubuntu **L**ong **T**erm **S**upport (LTS) release 16.04 at least until you are sure that you have completely finished replacing and testing your computer's hardware. You need a stable release with a long period of support to test your hardware changes with.

To monitor the temperature try Psensor from this answer: [How do I get the CPU temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/628117#628117). Budget graphics cards are so cheap that you ought to consider a cheap graphics card hardware upgrade and restore the overclocked 4.3 GHz settings in the BIOS back down to the default settings.

If you still want to overclock after you get the rest of the issues settled, comment about what your graphics card is or isn't and I will add information about how to do it using software from the default Ubuntu repositories.