# Ubuntu reboots unexpectedly

Tags: 16.04, reboot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and it reboots all of a sudden. I'm pretty sure this happens without any association with what I'm doing on the computer.

Here is my log from a few minutes or seconds before it happens:

```
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: New seat seat0.
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (Power Button)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event8 (Asus Wireless Radio Control)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (Video Bus)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Video Bus)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Lid Switch)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Sleep Button)
Apr 24 09:53:41 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event9 (Asus WMI hotkeys)
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
Apr 24 09:53:45 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet5: open_session called without kwallet5_key
Apr 24 09:53:48 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 24 09:53:48 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Apr 24 09:53:48 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "bolloename"
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:auth): (null): pam_sm_authenticate
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_close_session
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user bolloename by (uid=0)
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user bolloename by (uid=0)
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: New session c2 of user bolloename.
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_open_session
Apr 24 09:53:55 bolloename-X555BP lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: final socket path: /tmp/kwallet5_bolloename.socket
Apr 24 09:54:01 bolloename-X555BP gnome-keyring-daemon[1256]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Apr 24 09:54:01 bolloename-X555BP gnome-keyring-daemon[1256]: The SSH agent was already initialized
Apr 24 09:54:01 bolloename-X555BP gnome-keyring-daemon[1256]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Apr 24 09:54:01 bolloename-X555BP polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.70 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale es_CO.UTF-8)
Apr 24 09:55:04 bolloename-X555BP pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Apr 24 09:55:04 bolloename-X555BP pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Apr 24 09:55:04 bolloename-X555BP pkexec[2221]: bolloename: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/bolloename] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Apr 24 09:55:46 bolloename-X555BP systemd-logind[801]: Removed session c1.
Apr 24 09:55:46 bolloename-X555BP systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user lightdm
```

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

I've ran memtest for over 16 hours with 1 pass and 0 errors at 25%, test #3. I had to shut it down because it froze at that instance. It remained on test # 2 for over 13 hours, so I skipped it. Then that happened...

Also, here is the log that appears before the lock screen:

```
a[0.022630] [Firmware bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xD000000001000000)
[0.941981] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[0.941986] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI de list
[0.946154] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[1.021351] ACPI Error: (^^PB2_.VGA_.AFM7] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
[1.021364] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.VGA:LCDD._BCM, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
[1.021371] ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed  (20170531/video-364)
Ubuntu_16: clean, 2777420/1921360 files, 2438809/7679931 blocks
```

UPDATE #2:

sudo dmidecode -t memory

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0011
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: None
Locator: DIMM 0
Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
Type: DDR4
Type Detail: None
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer0
Serial Number: A1_SerialNum0
Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
Part Number: A1_PartNum0
Rank: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
Minimum Voltage: Unknown
Maximum Voltage: Unknown
Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0011
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 8192 MB
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: None
Locator: DIMM 1
Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
Type: DDR4
Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
Speed: 2133 MHz
Manufacturer: Micron
Serial Number: 00000000
Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
Part Number: 8ATF1G64HZ-2G1B1    
Rank: 1
Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
Minimum Voltage: 1.25 V
Maximum Voltage: 1.35 V
Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

sudo lshw -c memory

```
*-firmware              
   description: BIOS
   manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: X555BP.320
   date: 09/08/2017
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 8128KiB
   capacities (or capabilities*): pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
*-cache:0
   descripción: L1 caché
   id físico: 6
   ranura: L1 CACHE
   tamaño: 160KiB
   capacidad: 160KiB
   reloj: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capacidades: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
   configuración: level=1
*-cache:1
   description: L2 caché
   physical id: 7
   slot: L2 CACHE
   size: 1MiB
   capacity: 1MiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capacities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
*-memory
   description: Memoria de sistema
   physical id: 11
   slot: base
   tamaño: 8GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM [vacío]
      product: A1_PartNum0
      manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer0
      physical id: 0
      series: A1_SerialNum0
      slot: DIMM 0
      widht: 64 bits
 *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM Síncrono 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
      product: 8ATF1G64HZ-2G1B1
      manufacturer: Micron
      physical id: 1
      series: 00000000
      slot: DIMM 1
      size: 8GiB
      widht: 64 bits
      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the log for you with formatting that makes it easier to read.  But yeah, text format and **not** screenshots or even worse photographs of screens is appreciated.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Have you run a memtest?

Comment: Reboots? Or returns to login screen?

Comment: Reboots completely

Comment: In `terminal`... type `grep -i temp /var/log/syslog*` and see if you get anything that indicates a heat/temperature related shutdown.

Comment: @heynnema I did it, it shows Source ID (several prompts like this with different numbers, like 58 or 247) was not found when attempting to remove it. What's this?

Comment: @anonymous2 please look at the update. Thank you

Comment: It does sound like it could be a RAM issue (though heynnema also has a good point).  If you have multiple sticks of RAM, I would recommend taking out all but one stick, and seeing if it still does it.  If it does, swap it out for a different stick (*and* a different DIMM slot) and see what that yields.  While you're at it, install [some heat sensors](https://askubuntu.com/q/15832/527350) and keep an eye on them.  Also, while you are in the computer, move your hand over vital components to feel how hot they are.

Comment: @VicenteCH edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo dmidecode -t memory` and `sudo lshw -c memory`. Is this a laptop or desktop computer?

Comment: @heynnema included... It's a laptop

Comment: @anonymous2 will try today or tomorrow and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: @heynnema it looks weird because I translated some parts in spanish.

Comment: @VicenteCH move the SODIMM to the other slot and run memtest again. (Normally, for optimum performance, you add memory in pairs, so, two 4G SODIMMS in your case, instead of one 8G SODIMM).