# Getting ACPI Error and COMRESET failed (error=-32) during boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, inspiron

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in my Dell Inspiron 3521 (2013 model) for the past year. I have changed my hard disk with a Samsung 850 Pro SSD.

I've been using Samsung SSD for the past 5 months and I never faced this issue.
Suddenly Ubuntu got stuck while booting up, then I had to force shutdown, and after restarting I get a black screen with the messages shown in the screen photo and then finally it boots up.

This always happens now. My laptop never boots up on the first try. I also tried reinstalling the Ubuntu, but I still have the same issue.

[image: see error message here]

Edit-1:

After running `lsscsi --verbose` I got below response:

`[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 850  4B6Q  /dev/sda 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0]`

Edit-2:
I have also tried booting up from the live ubuntu USB, in that case as well I get the same error as in above photo.

Even to check if any ubuntu update has messed up I re-installed ubuntu 16.04 again and in it's first boot up it got stuck.

Comment: Check your CPU temperatures in the BIOS or install [Psensor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/628117#628117) and check your CPU temperatures after Ubuntu 16.04 has booted. Check your ACPI settings in the BIOS that they are compatible with your new Samsung 850 Pro SSD's settings that are recommended by the manufacturer (Samsung).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This looks like a storage hardware error. Storage drives, both SSDs and HDDs, although unlikely, can suddenly fail at any time. Can you please [verify the drive's integrity](/q/539184/175814) (e. g. from a live system) and report back? Thanks.

Comment: I can tell for sure that there is no issue for CPU temperature because when I start my laptop even after 12 hours of shut down period I still face this issue.

I have been using this SSD for past 5 months and its working fine, I have no idea what happened in the last two days that I am facing this issue. I have not changed any single settings in BIOS in last 6 months or so.

Comment: Just to confirm that SSD is ata3. You have to install this first. `sudo apt install lsscsi` and then run it: `lsscsi --verbose` Post info above. Have you run trim manually? Newer Ubuntu should be running it weekly: `  sudo fstrim -v /` and have you tried fsck on all ext4 partitions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 You also show an error on a USB device, unplug it.

Comment: I've never run the trim manually and I don't think there will be issue with the trim, I am using this SSD for past 5 months and never faced this issue. I will run fsck and will post the result above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by Ubuntu kernel update. Actually, this was a kernel issue, when I got this issue my Ubuntu was using Linux kernel version 4.13, but after some time the kernel update to 4.15 made it go away.

I knew that my hardware had no problem, I had run tests from above comments and all were fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and identified the faulty drive using `lssci`, as per advice from [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred). It was the only drive not showing up in the list. In my case, it turned out to be an external HD connected via eSATA.