# acpitz-virtual-0 temperature is wrong

Tags: hardware, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

When I run `sensors`, it returns the following:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
```

the `acpitz-virtual-0` temperature is always 48, and the fan never starts running as a consequence.

The `sensors-detect` gives the following output:

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: LENOVO 20ARS04V00 [ThinkPad T440s] (laptop)
# Kernel: 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz (6/69/1)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x1901

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:9c22 at 0000:00:1f.3.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: DPDDC-B (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 
Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

`systemctl status fancontrol.service` outputs:

```
● fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2018-07-27 13:06:29 CEST; 24h ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/fancontrol was not met
     Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
           man:pwmconfig(8)
```

and `lsmod | grep acpi` gives

```
thinkpad_acpi          94208  1
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd                    81920  28     snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
video                  45056  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
```

I have Ubuntu 18.4. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: *1.* 50C is normal temperature. *2.* Can you hear that fan is working? *3.* Sometimes `sensors` do not show real values for some hardware.

Comment: The fan does not start even when the temperature is ~80 °C. Some time ago, it started working suddenly (by stopped after some time) and apparently, the fan control uses the acpitz value, which does not change, and the fan therefore does not work.

Comment: Is fan working in BIOS or in GRUB, or in memtest86+? Do you have installed special fan-control software into Ubuntu? Also please add output of `systemctl status fancontrol.service` and `lsmod | grep acpi` to the question.

Comment: When I reboot the computer, the fan does not start at all. However, I am not sure it should, nor do I know how to test that the fan works in BIOS (since the CPU will be cold enough while in BIOS)

Comment: On my Asustek laptop the status of `fancontrol.service` is the same as yours. But I do not know about ThinkPad's fan-control. You can try to boot the system into Windows or previous version of Ubuntu live-cd to ensure that fan is working. Fan may have possible hardware fault after 5 years (counting from your CPU model release date).

Comment: The fan is working. As I said, the problem is that the temperature is always 48°C.

Comment: Alternate ways to get temperature: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/854029#854029 one thing to try: `paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t`

Comment: I know this, but how does it help me get my fan working?

Comment: @user2316602 If all the temperatures are accurate, then try using `tlp` instead of `fancontrol` It works perfectly for me. If the temperatures reported in the system (using the one liner I posted) then start searching there.

Comment: How does using tlp help me with wrong temperature for acpitz-virtual-0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by downgrading to an older version of the kernel. Not exactly the solution I would prefer. Hopefully, it will get fixed by next version of kernel in Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: It could help others if you specify the both the broken kernel version and the working kernel version.