# no additional drivers available ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hp, amd-graphics

I have a HP Probook 4540s.

My laptop is very hot in normal use.

And software&updates says 'no additional drivers available ubuntu'

This is my lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] (rev ff)
```

Please help me... Thank you!

---

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +52.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +42.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +46.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +32.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:       +127.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

Comment: See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature on tips on getting info from and about using sensors.

Comment: @Rinzwind this is my sesnors: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xCX7PYcWWV/

Comment: Your link states that "This paste expires on 2019-08-01"  so it is better to include it in the question. "temp6" is bad :P (Temp1 is almost always the CPU or CPU socket temperature)

Comment: temp6 is always at that temperature and it seems to be wrong.