# How to monitor temperature from the top panel in ubuntu 18.04 mate?

Tags: cpu, mate, temperature

I want to show an icon with the temperature of the cpu in the upper panel of ubuntu mate, something like the icon of the Taskbar of Core Temp in Windows, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the CPU temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature) See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/628117#628117

Comment: For MATE DE see my [new answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064901/66509) in duplicate thread.