# xserver-xorg-core2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8 Crash with SIGABRT in OsAbort()

Tags: 16.04, unity, xorg, intel-graphics, apport

How do I fix `Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error` on a Toshiba Satellite T135 13.3" laptop with Intel X4500M Integrated Graphics? I tried restarting the computer as advised, where I got this error message information:

Executable Path: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
  Package: xserver-xorg-core2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8
  Problem Type: Crash
  Title: Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in OsAbort().tmp.unity_support_test.0
  Apport Version: 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18
  Architecture: amd64

I clicked Continue to report the error and got to the desktop, from which I'm sending this question. Please advise if I need to provide more log details.

Comment: Can you run the laptop for long enough to [install Psensor app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/628117#628117) and get CPU temperature readings? If not you can also get it from the UEFI/BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
```