# High Temperature on Ubuntu Server 18.04 (ASUS Chromebox)

Tags: server, asus, overheating, temperature, chromeos

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on my ASUS Chromebox2. When issuing the command [`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`](https://askubuntu.com/a/15834) it returns the following:

```
43000
96500
42000
```

The numbers shown, indicate the temperature in millidegrees Celsius (m°C). So 96.5°C celsius is way to high. Since this is a newly bought Chromebox, is it possible that I misinterpreted the numbers or do I need to replace the hardware right after buying it?

EDIT:
Running lm-senors after some time of letting the Chromebox run, reports the following:

```
$ sudo sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +99.0°C
```

Comment: All temperatures look OK. That `pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0` is some wrong output misinterpreted by lm-sensors.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your answer :) But in the end, lm-sensors is just interpreting the values it found in /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp, right? Does this mean, that specific value is just off and I can ignore it? I hope so :)

Comment: That's correct. Some erroneous number.

Comment: If you could put that in an answer, I would accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that `96500` is a wrong number in `/sys/class/thermal/`.

This happens when a platform driver is not 100% compatible. It reads some register that is not showing real temperature on this device.

So just ignore this value. Everything else looks good.