# Cannon Lake Platform Controller Hub overheats on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, overheating, temperature

My Laptop (Alienware m15 - 2018) Platform Controller Hub (Cannon Lake PCH) is overheating on Ubuntu 20.04 (without running any app) unlike Microsoft windows 10, can you please tell me how can I solve this problem?

> Note that I'm using **Ubuntu installed on an external SSD drive**, so the USB hub controller is managing the communication with the system.

[image: img]

I'm using the "*Temperature without third-party apps*" approach from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/854029) as follows:

`paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'`

```sh
acpitz           60.0°C
iwlwifi_1        59.0°C
x86_pkg_temp     59.0°C
acpitz           27.8°C
INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
SEN2             62.0°C
SEN3             56.0°C
SEN4             66.0°C
SEN5             45.0°C
SEN1             54.0°C
pch_cannonlake   85.0°C
B0D4             59.0°C
```

#### Edit:

Using `lscpu` I get:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-11
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           158
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        10
CPU MHz:                         2200.000
CPU max MHz:                     4100.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4399.99
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       192 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        1.5 MiB
L3 cache:                        9 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-11
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cach
                                 e flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts 
                                 rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperf
                                 mperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx e
                                 st tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_
                                 1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer
                                  aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowpre
                                 fetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd i
                                 brs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept
                                  vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust sgx bmi1 avx2 
                                 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clfl
                                 ushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves 
                                 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_
                                 window hwp_epp sgx_lc md_clear flush_l1d
```

Comment: What CPU do you have? `lscpu` should tell you, if you don't know. Also, if there is dust in your computer vents, remove it.

Comment: @cocomac thanks for your remark, I have updated my question with the output of `lscpu`, I already cleaned the fans but the problem is still.