# Can't get CPU temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature

I'm having trouble getting the temperature of the CPU.
I tried using `lm-sensors`, but it does not find any module (I did the configuration and kmod start).
I checked the local files located here: `/sys/class/thermal` and all that I can find is cooling_device folders (0 to 11).

Here is the configuration:

- `Ubuntu server 20.04.4 LTS`
- `5.4.0-159-generic`, updated to `5.15.0-83-generic` regarding @noisefloor comment
- `AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics`

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your CPU is newer than the Kernel, the CPU was released in 2021, Linux Kernel 5.4 dates back to 2019. Thus it may be that the Kernel doesn't support all features of the CPU.
Enable the HWE Stack in Ubuntu 20.4. and install the latest HWE Kernel, which is 5.15. This hopefully resolves your problem.

Comment: I updated the kernel, now `uname -r` shows `5.15.0-83-generic`. `/sys/class/thermal` still contains the cooling_device, nothing else.

Comment: @karel no this does not help since I'm already using lm-sensors.

Answer (score 0):

@Morti, Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu and StackExchange! I was asked to edit my answer, which--on further inspection--does seem a bit feeble (entirely my words, not the one who asked me to edit), even if  mildly helpful. I can do better than that!
    I just need to clarify: did you mean that the site that answered this question at length? I have to admit: it has far more answers than I originally thought: 21 different answers! Please understand I am not at all questioning whether you tried all 21 in-depth answers and got almost nowhere (referring, now, to your response to my original message) aside from "module nvme-pci-0900 and k10temp-pci-00c3...,", that does seem to cover quite a bit in terms of several different methods.
Just to rewrite my [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature#15833) to the above-mentioned site, I also wanted to add some great examples that cover more than just `lm-sensors`, with `sensors-detect`, and the `service kmod start` (though I do want to note that about a page and a half down from the start of the first answer, just before the 2nd answer begins, @knb made a comment that began, "On my 13.04 system...," about `sudo service module-init-tools start`. Well, it may have been juxtaposed but the point is that there was one alternative to the `sudo service kmod start`, depending on the system.
    The 2nd answer (with 240 by it) mentions an applet for Gnome Panel, **"Hardware Sensors Monitor"** while the 3rd states that, "A good indicator for monitoring temperature, *as well as* fan speeds and voltages from all sensors, called **psensor.**  And while a few do repeat themselves, varying only slightly, there are more besides the lm-sensors and the like. I would love to give directions (more than I have) but as these are all from one Ask Ubuntu page, this does make it easier insofar as not having to go very far for such varied choices! Take care.

MichaelTheGamer

Comment: This post was my starting point. I used sensors-detect several times, and of course I tried it after upgrading the kernel. The only metrics I can see are stats from module nvme-pci-0900 and k10temp-pci-00c3 (both pci adpaters)