# What is the easiest way to record my desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

I want to make a video tutorial on some Ubuntu functionality but don't know how to record it.