# Video Recording in Ubuntu

Tags: video, desktop-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

What Video Recording software is there that matches (or better) than the software version in Windows for FRAPS and WeGame?

Already tried **istanbul** (honestly it sucks) and the last update was when dinosaurs ruled ;) http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul

Then i tried **recordmydesktop** which is very good BUT in only saves in ogg. It also has not received any updates since King Kong and Godzilla did the Tango ;) http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/news.php

Also tried **ffmpeg** with the command line option to screen capture. Good also but..

Am looking for a gui friendly (Friendlier than gtk-recordmydesktop) recording program for Ubuntu that has options to several formats and quality (Like the options when saving a video in openshot which has a very nice system to select the quality and objective of the video like youtube, vimeo, etc..)

And that it uses correctly cpu, memory and not kill the system for recording in 2D, 3D and OpenGL (Via Wine) programs.