# What is the best desktop/screen recorder?

Tags: desktop-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

I am trying to record my desktop. I tried Desktop Recorder and when it came out the image was very pixelated, so I'm looking for a better application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try 3:

- [Recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/)
- [Istanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul/)
- [XVidCap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net)

But could you define "best"?

Comment: ok i tryed all and XVidCap works the best for me thanks