# I want to change the position of the launcher items

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to rearrange the icons in Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-the-icons-in-unity-launcher)

I have added a quicklist launcher to Unity, it sits at the bottom of the list, I want to change that to another position easily with minimal effort / programs.

[image]

ie: I want to move `firefox` from being the 2nd item in the list to the first position bellow the dash button.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, could you either add a picture to show what you mean, or describe it in more detail? To me it sounds as if what you want is simply solved by drag and drop, but I can't believe that such an easy answer is what you are looking for...

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the other answer works for 11.10 for both Ubuntu and Ubuntu2D desktop environments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Left-click and hold your application icon for couple of seconds then move it over the launcher to desired place.

Comment: On 12.10, I had to start the application first to be able to move the icon...

Answer (score 4):

Drag the firefox icon some out of the launcher until a white bar appears where the icon has been. THen continue to drag the firefox icon up. The white bar will show the new position of the launcher icon. Then drop the icon into its new position.

Edit: I run 11.10, unity 3D:

```
$ more /etc/issue
Ubuntu 11.10 \n \l

$ unity --version
unity 4.24.0
```

And it looks like this:

[image]