# How to change the size and order of  the launcher panel?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

I have downloaded 12.04 and installed it under VirtualBox. The launcher in its default format is unsuitable for my needs.

The two main factors that I need to edit are (1) the size of the panel; and (2) the order in which the launch items are listed.

From the settings I have reviewed, it is not clear how to do this. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

Its now very simple to change the launcher size in 12.04:

- [How to resize the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18345/how-do-i-resize-the-unity-launcher)

There is a similar excellent answer for moving icons in the launcher:

- [Is there an easy way to rearrange or move the icons in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-or-move-the-icons-in-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: Part 2 does not solve the issue for me.  I am aware of how to reorder the icons but within a virtualbox VM it doesn't work

Comment: To move icons in 12.04, long click on the icon then move directly up or down.

Answer (score 2):

I use myUnity to do such changes

[image]

Comment: I don't have that icon on my launcher. Can you explain how you got it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in 12.04 and Unity-2D.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-unity-2d-resize-launcher.html

Answer (score 0):

To resize the panel you can use Unsettings.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

About the order, well, you can just drag and drop the items in what order you please.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple.
To resize the Unity Launcher you have to go to the desktop Background options where you will find the slider which you can use to adapt the size.

Cheers
Jeroen Dronkers