# How to adjust Unity icons and and pane size?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the size and order of  the launcher panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126886/how-to-change-the-size-and-order-of-the-launcher-panel)

I'd like to use smaller icons (24x24 or so) to make my Unity panel thinner and "higher" (to let more icons fit vertically).  How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size in "Appearance" menu. To access it you can open dash and type "Appearance" or just right click on desktop and click "Change background".