# How can I rearrange the icons in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to rearrange or move the icons in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-or-move-the-icons-in-the-unity-launcher)

Given that I have no choice to move the launcher from the left of the screen. How do I change the order in which icons appear? 
For example, LibreOffice icons appear at a variety of positions, And I'd like them to be grouped. I'd also prefer to have the most commonly used icons visible on screen and only have to go scrolling for the less common ones as I only use a desktop screen, no hand held devices.