# How to make a set of screenshots automatically?

Tags: screencast

I would like to do an animated gif file. Thus I need all images and then I can build the gif file with gimp or convert.

But in order to obtain the images how can I do a set of successive screenshots ? What I would like to record is a vibration movement of a molecule or a crystal (using jmol or j-ice).

Actually, I want to do a screencast ...

Comment: Why don't you use a screencast tool instead? cut the clip and that's it, far better quality than a gif.

Comment: In addition to @UriHerrera's comment: if you insist to make a gif from images, you can extract the proper jpg frames from the screencast by using the ffmpeg tool, as mentioned here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8040839

Comment: Can you advice a simple tools in order to make a screencast ? please

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast should cover that.

Answer (score 2):

### How to create an animated (GIF) screenshot

*([Cross-posted from my answer here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/119060/36459))*

Added bonus with this approach is that you can post the screencast without embed tags on any forum that includes animated GIFs as embedded like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-or-move-the-icons-in-the-unity-launcher/39819#39819)

The answers prior to mine have clearly answered how to create a video screencast. Now if you just want to show an animated screenshot, essentially an extremely short screencast in an image format (GIF, and not more than ~10 sec), it's also easy.

First create a screencast of what you want to show in the animated GIF. Then follow the instructions below...

You'll need Gimp, mplayer (**WARNING!** NOT mplayer2) and mencoder. Issue the following commands to install them.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
sudo apt-get install mplayer
sudo apt-get install mencoder
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Alternatively, you can install them from the Synaptic package manager that comes with Ubuntu.

The following command breaks your screencast into a number of jpeg or png (based on which command you choose) images:

```
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 2 eagles.avi -vo jpeg:outdir=Desktop/animated
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 2 eagles.avi -vo png:z=9:outdir=Desktop/animated
```

*Where, `-ss 0:0:33` tells mplayer where you begin (0 hours, 0 minutes, 33 seconds), `-endpos 2` tells mplayer where to stop (2 minutes), `z=9` sets compression level for the output png images to 9, `Desktop/animated` is the directory (~/Desktop/animated/) where you want the images to be output to.*

You can also tell mplayer where to stop, as a specific time, like so:

```
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 0:1:12 eagles.avi -vo jpeg:outdir=Desktop/animated
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:0:33 -endpos 0:1:12 eagles.avi -vo png:z=9:outdir=Desktop/animated
```

Now you have the images, but you need to combine them into a single, animated GIF. This is really simple:

- Start Gimp > File > Open as Layers > browse to the directory (~/Desktop/animated/), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all images, and click 'Open'.
- Simple hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or go to File > Save As... and name the image as 'animated**.gif**' > hit 'Save' > check 'Save as Animation' radio button > hit 'Export' > in the next window, simply hit 'Save' unless you know what you are doing.

That's it. You have your animated GIF ready!

**Here's an example:**

[image: Animated GIF screenshot]