# Rearrange icons in unity Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons

Can someone help me in rearranging the icons in my Ubuntu 12.04 unity launcher. The left click hold and move is not working for me. Is there a better and clean way which would also survive a reboot?

Comment: From memory: This means you are using unity 2d. So log out and choose Unity 3D. If that does not solve it check if you can install another driver for your video card. If both are not the answer please add a comment into your question

Answer (score 1):

Left-click and hold the icon briefly and it will detach itself and can be moved up or down on the launcher. See https://askubuntu.com/a/170453/115414