# Is there an easy way to rearrange or move the icons in the Unity launcher? (doesn't work anymore)

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, gui, unity-dash

Unity doesn't [seem](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/31784/changing-the-order-of-components.html) to allow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-rearrange-or-move-the-icons-in-the-unity-launcher) anymore.  Is re-ordering usually accomplished with the suggested plugins?  Are those installed via apt?

Comment: That forum post you linked is about a game engine called Unity, totally different to Ubuntu's graphical shell called Unity.

Comment: I think you might just be confused, or suffering from a bug. So try restarting your machine, and note that you have to drag the icon to the right, *then* drag it up or down.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the Desktop, press and hold Super (Windows) key. The first 10 Launcher icons will get numbers on top. Then left-click on the icon you want to move and slide it wherever you want it to go. It will be renumbered automagically.

Why developers made this so obscure I don't know.

Comment: You don't have to hold Super while rearranging (at least not on my machine, running Unity 7.2.6, Ubuntu 14.04).