# Screencast with both mic and system sounds at the same time

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, video, screencast

I'd like to make a screencast that records both mic (audio input) and system sounds (audio output) at the same time. For example, so that I can capture a screencast while talking to someone on Skype and capture both sides of the conversation. How can I do this? (I'm using Natty if it matters.)

So far I have tried Kazam, RecordMyDesktop and Tibesti. (Tibesti explicitly has this feature but it doesn't seem to work. Kazam has existing enhancement requests for this feature.)

Please provide complete instructions/options, like those given [for running RecordMyDesktop from the command line in this generic screencasting answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast/4433#4433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. Been pulling my hair out forever searching for an answer that isn't needlessly complicated.

Install and use [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com) (aka OBS Studio). Seriously, that's it.

You can follow the [Linux installation instructions](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux) or just [use the Snap store](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio).

You can configure OBS to simultaneously record:

- screen (XSHM screen capture)
- mic (PulseAudio audio input capture)
- system sounds (PulseAudio audio output capture)

Comment: Just tried OBS on Ubuntu 20.04 - it works perfectly! Before that, I have spent a lot of time to set up other screen recorders (e.g. SimpleScreenRecorder and Kazam), which was unsuccessful. Output of OBS has excellent quality of video, microphone and system audio. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Look for a way to combine sound channels instead of looking for multirecording screencast app. [How to mix voice and audio on Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20121218101949/http://blog.flipzu.com/2011/02/how-to-mix-voice-and-audio-on-ubuntu.html) (archive.org copy) describes how to do it with PulseAudio. This tutorial seems to be based on [Weekend Project: Record From Skype Calls and Other Apps on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/weekend-project-record-skype-calls-and-other-apps-linux) (linux.com). IIRC there are also similar in spirit tricks for JACK)

Answer (score -1):

I just recorded a quick screencast and wrote up a blog post on how to do this. My tutorial is in the context of recording the audio from a Google Hangouts call, but the same concepts apply to anything. As you can see in my screencast tutorial, you can be recording a screencast in addition to everything else that's going on. Here's a link to the tutorial: https://leehblue.com/record-phone-calls-audacity-ubuntu/

Comment: How did you achieve this, the steps are important...

Answer (score -3):

Hope this is what you are looking for: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWyfG4PVpms.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Alright. I'll keep that in mind next time around.

Comment: @rigved I do not get the same options as the screencaster, could it be a hardware capability issue, or do I need to pick a specific sound profile? see http://askubuntu.com/questions/63533/which-sound-profile-will-allow-me-to-simultaneously-hear-and-record-system-audio (created a separate question for the more specific issue)

Comment: video has been removed :(