# Which sound profile will allow me to simultaneously hear and record system audio + microphone input?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm trying to [screencast with both mic and system sounds at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57448/screencast-with-both-mic-and-system-sounds-at-the-same-time). Previously this didn't work, but I have found that fiddling with the sound profile brings me a step closer.

To fiddle with sound profile:

- Click on Sound menu
- Select "Sound Preferences..."
- Select "Hardware" tab
- Choose the device to configure (I have two "Internal Audio" and "Logitech USB Headset")
- Select option from Profile dropdown
- Click "Test Speakers" to test output

So far so good. Previously I had Internal Audio set to "Analog Stereo Duplex" and the headset also on "Analog Stereo Duplex". When I recorded a screencast in Tibesti and played it back, I could hear myself but not the system sounds (for example, music player or Skype call).

I switched Internal Audio to "Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)". Under the "Output" tab I selected internal audio as the output. When I recorded a screencast in Tibesti and played it back, I could hear myself and the system sounds. Unfortunately, I couldn't hear the system sounds **while recording**, which means screencasting a Skype call couldn't work.

The internal audio profiles are: Analog Stereo Duplex, Analog Stereo Output, Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input, Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958), Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input, Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output, Analog Stereo Input, Off.

The headset audio profiles are: Analog Stereo Duplex, Analog Stereo Output, Analog Stereo Input, Off.

Which profile combination and input/output selection will allow me to simultaneously hear and record system audio + microphone input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No sound profile selection will achieve the results you are looking for. Instead you could [mix voice and audio channels](https://web.archive.org/web/20121218101949/http://blog.flipzu.com/2011/02/how-to-mix-voice-and-audio-on-ubuntu.html) (follow link for step-by-step details).

You might want start with this article from the same blog for background [High quality audio broadcasting with Flipzu and Ubuntu Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702073333/http://blog.flipzu.com/2010/10/high-quality-audio-broadcasting-with.html), or this "weekend project" for a lot more technical detail: [Record From Skype Calls and Other Apps on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/367395-weekend-project-record-from-skype-calls-and-other-apps-on-linux).

Comment: Sadly, both of the links to flipzu are now broken.

Comment: I just replaced the links by the ones in the wayback machine.

Answer (score 1):

install & use pavucontrol

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

executable : /usr/bin/pavucontrol

this software monitor audio output and can map audio input to monitors.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; so far pavucontrol looks simply like an alternative to sound preferences so I must be missing something - I get the same profile options under the "Configuration" tab, and it isn't obvious to me how to map the audio input, can you please explain how? thanks!

Comment: ah, found http://blog.stebalien.com/2009/03/howto-ones-linux-computer-with.html and now I understand better

Comment: so I've figured out how to use pavucontrol to record the output (monitor) rather than input, so I can hear the output and have it recorded at the same time, but now I can't record the input - I'd like to hear the output and record both output and input - do I need to pick a specific profile in the pavucontrol Configuration tab?