# Video editor to create professional appearance

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast

I've been very impressed with [this screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Oggl7c6tVQ).

Is there a simple way to create a professional-looking screencast using open software on Ubuntu? I'm mainly interested in good-looking transitions between images and videos.

Comment: Just to make clear - this ScreenCast question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) is available - you could say this is a duplicate since how "professional" any application is debatable!

Comment: I moved my answer to the other topic.

Comment: That's fancy indeed. I don't know of any tools that has this built-in, but there are video editors that can add nice transitions between videos. There are also tools that can be used to add overlays. So while you probably won't get it in a single tool, you should be able to achieve similar effects by using specialized tools.

Comment: Given that we have an exhaustive list of Screencast tools (as linked above) I think you're really looking to pair a tool from that list and a video editor. You may wish to change the subject of  your question to better focus it to "Video editor to create professional appearance" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

## [kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) [image: install kdenlive]

> Kdenlive is a free open-source video editor for GNU/Linux and FreeBSD, which supports DV, AVCHD and HDV editing. Kdenlive relies on several other open source projects, such as FFmpeg, the MLT video framework and Frei0r effects.

[image: Kdenlive main window]

Kdenlive is easily the best video editor currently available for Ubuntu. There is also a GTK frontend for MLT framework (OpenShot) but it has less features and worse user interface.

Kdenlive supports a wide array of video formats, images and transitions. The rendering tool has ready presets for most situations like Youtube, DVD, different mobile devices, etc. so you don't need to be an expert on video compression.

You can get it from Ubuntu's repository, but I'd suggest you get the latest version from project site. They even have a repository set up for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

2020 update:

## [Olive Video Editor](https://www.olivevideoeditor.org/)

I think now the best option (even being on alpha) is Olive, IMO better than [the alternatives](https://www.slant.co/topics/2073/%7Evideo-editors-for-linux).

Maybe a downside is that Olive targets professional users.

[image: screenshot]

## [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org/)

More general purpose.

[image: screenshot]

## [OpenShot](http://openshot.org/)

Great video editor without need to install all the KDE stuff.

> OpenShot Video Editor is a free, open-source video editor for Linux, Mac, and Windows licensed under the GPL version 3.0.
>
> ### Features
>
> OpenShot has many great features, such as trimming and arranging videos, adjusting audio levels, transitions between videos, compositing multiple layers of video, chroma-key / green screen effect, and support of most formats and codecs.
>
> What really sets OpenShot apart from other video editors is the easy-to-use user interface. We have worked very hard to create a video editor that everyone can enjoy!

- [Screencasts](http://openshot.org/videos/)