# Video Recorder Tool (Screencast) for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, screencast

I was looking at this post [How can I record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) which mentions some Video Recorders (Screencast) that I was looking for but some of them are more than 8 months old with not one single update made to them. I am looking for a Screencast that is at least update recently and that I know that if I keep using it I could count on it being updated.

The most important part is video recording but sound is good too. Maybe a window area, mouse tracking, etc. But it needs to be up to date and not abandoned or very old.

And of course that works in 11.10 and has in mind to work in 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recent I answer I just gave: [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast/95103#95103).

I'm also looking into kdenlive for video editing. See: [Video editor to create professional appearance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60944/video-editor-to-create-professional-appearance)

Comment: +1 because the list is good but the problem there is that some are out of date, others are not developed anymore and others have some very weird problems or are to tough to use or to limited to used. Basically it boils down to 2 or 3 of them but to start looking for each of them and see which one starts development again kills this question. I am looking for a real screencast project that keeps on working into something that eventually will rival fraps and wegame which are the best two right now.. for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kazam: http://www.twm-kd.com/category/linux/kazam/

It's an up-to-date screencast software with support for modern desktops like Unity and PulseAudio.

Comment: Going to test this out. Thanks for the link and an actually very updated software.