# How can I Screencast games in Ubuntu with Live Commentary

Tags: 11.10, screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

sorry for the duplicate question! I found another similiar question here:

- [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

But I did not find an answer there

---

I would like to make live commentaries (record my voice in real-time over the speaker sound). Is it possible? I did not find a solution in:
Instambul (not configurable)
GTK-RecordMyDesktop (not found any setting about it)
XVidCap (not configurable)
Kazam (low FPS)
Tibesti (not installable in Oneiric)
Tested glc but seems to not work in oneiric...

Thanks for your answers and forgive my english (I'm Italian!)

Kind regards,
Roberto! :D

Comment: Using nvidia binary drivers? They are known for working poorly with screencasting. Of course without them you get poor framerates anyway, so there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: In particular, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/33663/63886) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/33663/63886) from the above question.