# Good screen recording program

Tags: 11.10, screen, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

Can someone recommend a good program for recording screen activity, and saving it in a popular video format such as h.264?

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

(EDIT) Found the answer to my questions here [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) :)

Answer (score 2):

try this program GTK Recoder frankly i didn't use it before put most user use it in linux so I think it's must be good

try this Desktop Recorder

you can search it in ubuntu software center and write that

> gtk-recordmydesktop

and this explain for it  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VYaAn8UI-8

and finally program i found it in this link http://www.noobslab.com/2012/01/kazam-screen-recorder-for-ubuntu-1110.html